# Split a string at specific positions

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Given a string of alphanumerical characters, how to split it simply and quickly at the **center** of continuous letter-substrings? Is there an elegant and fast solutions out there in the "computational universe"?

The splitter should create "syllables" with one digit as a nucleus for each syllable, that is, at the end there should be **only one digit per sublist**. When there are more letter characters between digits, letters should be shared by the bordering digits (here I simulated a half share, distributing towards the right bordering digit in case of an odd number of letters), and starting and ending letter-sequences should be just attached to the closest digit.

```
"xxx00xxx000x0xx0xxxx000xx0xx" (* original string *)

"xxx0 | 0x | xx0 | 0 | 0 | x0x | x0xx | xx0 | 0 | 0x | x0xx" (* intermediate *)

{"xxx0", "0x", "xx0", "0", "0", "x0x", "x0xx", "xx0", "0", "0x", "x0xx"} (* end *)
```

Note that the string never contains spaces by default.

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Wizard, you're not slow at all, I purposefully edited out my own lame solution to prevent any bias, and with it the specification (unpurposefully). Please see edit.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Take each continuous sequence, such as `xxxx` or `00` and put a separator in the middle.  Then split at the separators. I'd implement that but it's not elegant.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Almost, with the minor addition, that continuous digit sequences should be split at **each** digit (now of course this is not really the issue here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a faster version of István's function:

```
split[s_String] :=
  StringReplace[s, {
    StartOfString ~~ l : LetterCharacter .. :> l,
    l : LetterCharacter .. ~~ EndOfString   :> l,
    l : LetterCharacter .. :>
          StringInsert[l, " ", 1 + Quotient[StringLength@l, 2] ],
    d : Repeated[DigitCharacter, {2, ∞}] :>
          StringJoin @ Riffle[Characters@d, " "]
  }] // StringSplit
```

Timings:

```
str = StringJoin @@ (RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {500000}] /. {0 -> "0", 1 -> "x"});

First@AbsoluteTiming[istvan = splitIstvan@str;]
First@AbsoluteTiming[mrwizard = split@str;]
istvan === mrwizard
```

> ```
> 0.7710441
>
> 0.4260243
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Good point, the longer list the better speed up +1! The relative timings `0.7` for `5 10^4`, `0.57` for `5 10^5` and `0,56` for `2.5 10^6`.

Comment: Even more optimized, amazing!

Comment: Since it gives the fastest and clearest solution (praising myself as well), I've accepted this answer.

Comment: @István thanks :-)

Answer (score 11):

This basically uses the method as outlined in the question:

```
split[str_] := Module[{pos, str1},
  pos = Ceiling[Mean /@ StringPosition[str, 
      Repeated[LetterCharacter, {2, Infinity}], Overlaps -> False]];
  str1 = StringInsert[str, " ", pos];
  pos = StringPosition[str1, Repeated[DigitCharacter, {2}], 
      Overlaps -> True][[All, 2]];
  StringSplit[StringInsert[str1, " ", pos]]]

split["000xxxx0000xxx00x0"]
```

> ```
> {"0", "0", "0xx", "xx0", "0", "0", "0x", "xx0", "0x0"}
> ```

**Edit**

Apparently I misunderstood the splitting rules. Hopefully I got it right this time

```
split[str_] := 
 Module[{pos, str1}, 
  pos = Ceiling[
    Mean /@ StringPosition[str, 
      DigitCharacter ~~ Repeated[LetterCharacter] ~~ DigitCharacter]];
  str1 = StringInsert[str, " ", pos];
  pos = StringPosition[str1, Repeated[DigitCharacter, {2}], 
     Overlaps -> True][[All, 2]];
  StringSplit[StringInsert[str1, " ", pos]]]
```

Testing the solution of the string in the question:

```
split["xxx00xxx000x0xx0xxxx000xx0xx"]
```

> ```
> {"xxx0", "0x", "xx0", "0", "0", "x0x", "x0xx", "xx0", "0", "0x", "x0xx"}
> ```

Comment: This has some problems: for example it splits `"000xx00xxx"` into `{"0", "0", "0x", "x0", "0x", "xx"}` instead of `{"0", "0", "0x", "x0", "0xxx"}`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar In that case I misunderstood your splitting rules.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect the rules more correctly. If you could update your solution, I would gladly run it against the others again, as I see that it has potential!

Comment: @IstvánZachar I've updated my solution.

Comment: Interesting alternative - +1.

Answer (score 9):

This is a [Euclidean Allocation](http://nctr.pmel.noaa.gov/time/resources/glossary.html) operation on a one-dimensional grid.  That immediately suggests use of `Nearest`:

```
Clear[midsplit];
midsplit[s_String] := Module[
   {digits = First[#] & /@  StringPosition[s, DigitCharacter], runs},
   runs = Accumulate[
     Length[#] & /@  
      Split[Last[#] & /@ ( 
         Nearest[digits, #] & /@ Range[StringLength[s]])]];
   MapThread[
    StringTake[s, {#1, #2}] &, {Most[Prepend[runs + 1, 1]], runs}] 
   ];
midsplit[s_String] /; 
   Length[StringCases[s, DigitCharacter]] == 0 := {s};
```

(The last line takes care of cases where no digit appears at all; `Nearest` chokes on an empty list for the first argument.)  Most of the code is devoted to reformatting the input into a binary raster representation (the computation of `digits`) and then using the results of `Nearest` to extract the associated substrings (the computation of `runs` and subsequent application of `StringTake`).

Comment: +1 for brevity and interesting idea / link. Mine is faster for large strings, but yours is shorter and reveals interesting techniques/algorithm. I actually tested on random strings of length several thousands and our results agree.

Comment: I did the same kind of testing :-).  Your algorithm scales exceptionally well.

Comment: Thanks :-). I tried hard to both make it linear time and avoid imperative style with assignments etc. For very large lists, one has to lift the `$IterationLimit`. I could have used less rules, but then `ff` would not be tail-recursive in M sense (it would affect `$RecursionLimit` then, which I normally try to avoid at all costs). Also, pattern-matcher can be nicely utilized here to implement look-ahead behavior in a clear fashion, which I exploited as well. I actually think that linked lists are under-used in Mathematica programming.

Answer (score 9):

In the meantime, I figured out a quite simple way, and I was amazed, that it turned out quite fast - the same reason why Heike's solution is fast: using the string pattern matcher is perhaps the best option here.

```
splitIstvan[s_String] := StringSplit@StringReplace[s, {
     StartOfString ~~ l : LetterCharacter .. :> l,
     l : LetterCharacter .. ~~ EndOfString :> l,
     l : LetterCharacter .. :> (StringTake[l, 
         Floor[StringLength@l/2]] <> " " <> 
        StringTake[l, -Ceiling[StringLength@l/2]]),
     d : DigitCharacter .. :> StringJoin@Riffle[Characters@d, " "]
     }];


str = StringJoin @@ (RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000}] /. {0 -> "0", 
  1 -> "x"});

{
 First@AbsoluteTiming[whuber = splitWhuber@str;],
 First@AbsoluteTiming[
   leonid = Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, splitLeonid@str];],
 First@AbsoluteTiming[heike = splitHeike@str;],
 First@AbsoluteTiming[istvan = splitIstvan@str;]
 }

{istvan === whuber, istvan === leonid, istvan === heike}
```

> ```
> {12.0120211, 0.0624001, 0.1092002, 0.0312001}
>
> {True, True, True}
> ```

Comment: Interesting. I somehow had a hunch that string-based operations won't be enough here, and you just proved me wrong. +1.

Comment: Excellent solution: it will be difficult to improve on its performance or brevity.

Comment: Well I actually gave up on the string patternmatcher and went on to do some algorithmic trial-and-error, that is why I posted the question. And then came this idea.

Answer (score 8):

Linked lists seem to be a good data structure to implement matching with some look-ahead behavior - which is what is needed here. Here is a linear-time solution based on linked lists:

```
ClearAll[toLinkedList];
toLinkedList[l_] := Fold[{#2, #1} &, {}, Reverse@l]
```

This computes the distance to the next zero in the linked list:

```
Clear[nzl];
nzl[{}, _] := 0;
nzl[{Except["0"], tail_}, len_] := nzl[tail, len + 1];
nzl[{"0", _}, len_] := len;
```

This is a main recursive "engine"

```
ClearAll[ff];
ff[accum_, current_, {}, _, _] := ll[accum, Flatten@current];

ff[accum_, current_, {h : Except["0"], tail_}, nextZeroFullLength_, nextZeroLength_] /;  
     nextZeroLength == IntegerPart[(nextZeroFullLength + 1)/2] :=
  ff[ll[accum, Flatten@{current, h}], {}, tail, nextZeroFullLength, nextZeroLength - 1];

ff[accum_, current_, {h : Except["0"], tail_}, nextZeroFullLength_, nextZeroLength_] :=
  ff[accum, {current, h}, tail, nextZeroFullLength, nextZeroLength - 1];

ff[accum_, current_, {"0", t : {"0", tail_}}, _, _] :=
  ff[ll[accum, Flatten@{current, {"0", {}}}], {}, t, 1, 1];

ff[accum_, current_, {"0", t : {_, {"0", _}}}, _, _] :=
  ff[ll[accum, Flatten@{current, "0"}], {}, t, nzl[t, 0], nzl[t, 0] - 1];

ff[accum_, current_, {"0", tail_}, _, _] :=
  ff[accum, {current, "0"}, tail, nzl[tail, 0], nzl[tail, 0] - 1];
```

and the final function:

```
ClearAll[splitString];
splitString[str_String] :=
  Block[{ll, result},
    SetAttributes[ll, HoldAllComplete];
    Map[StringJoin, List @@ Flatten[#, Infinity, ll]] &@
      ff[ll[], {}, #, nzl[#, 0], 0] &@toLinkedList@Characters[str]
];
```

You use this as

```
splitString["xxx00xxx000x0xx0xxxx000xx0xx"]
```

Not sure if this is elegant though, it's clearly not too brief.

Comment: +1  It might not be brief, but it's quick!  (And scales well.)  It is noteworthy, though, that splitString["xxx"] returns {"x", "xx"}.  Not necessarily wrong: the behavior for an input with no digits was not specified.

Comment: I have some problems when run on strings of length 10000: `$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >>`

Comment: @Istvan Just wrap the code into `Block[{$IterationLimit = Infinity}, splitString[...]]`. This is safe.

Comment: Indeed, and now it qualifies as the second fastest. Nice recursive solution.

Comment: @Istvan Thanks. So far, it looks like you've got to accept your own solution, unless someone comes up with something yet shorter and faster (which I doubt) :-)

Comment: I'll give it a lot of time, you can never know.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

I fixed two shortcomings in my earlier submission:

```
f[str_] :=
   Module[{r1},
       r1 = StringReplace[
            str, {d : NumberString /; StringLength[d] > 1 :>  
            StringInsert[d, " ", Range[2, StringLength[d]]]}];
  StringSplit@
    FixedPoint[
       StringReplace[#, (d1 : DigitCharacter) ~~ (w : 
       LetterCharacter ..) ~~ (d2 : DigitCharacter) :> 
       d1 ~~ StringInsert[w, " ", Floor[StringLength[w]/2] + 1] ~~ 
       d2] &, r1]
       ]
```

The first `StringReplace` inserts a break between all adjacent digits. The second `StringReplace` places a break in any run of letters. These two breaks are sufficient to parse all the cases.

`FixedPoint` is needed because the second instance of `StringReplace` is not always able to find all the relevant cases to replace on the first pass.

There was also a second rule in the first `StringReplace` that was a sloppy (and faulty) hack.

Examples:

```
f["xxx00xxx000x0xx0xxxx000xx0xx"]

(* Out *) 
{"xxx0", "0x", "xx0", "0", "0", "x0x", "x0xx", "xx0", "0", "0x", \
  "x0xx"}

f["x0xxx00x00"]

(*Out *) 
{"x0x", "xx0", "0", "x0", "0"}
```

**Speed check** using István's metric:

```
str = StringJoin @@ (RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10000}] /. {0 -> "0", 
  1 -> "x"});
First[f[str] // AbsoluteTiming]

(* Out*)
0.037927
```

Comment: While it's pretty fast, it fails on e.g. this: `"x0xxx00x00"`, and returns `{"x0x", "xx00", "x00"}` where not all the digits are split. BTW, you can use space instead of `" | "` as a dummy, which simplifies cases.

Comment: I'll check the failing condition. Regarding " | ", anything can be a separator; I simply matched the separator to produce output like yours.

Comment: You're right. There is something wrong with the code (I mixed up code from two different attempts.)

Comment: @István The updated version works better, I believe.