# How to I extract the element name of a chemical compound in a string?

Tags: string-manipulation, chemistry

Say I have a compound Fe3O4, and I want to separate the name of elements and number. The code I write for separate number is

```
atomicMassAlloys[Alloy_String] := StringCases[Alloy, DigitCharacter]
```

But I do not know how to separate the name of element

Comment: Related: [(3443)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3443/121)

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of how to work with chemicals the *Mathematica* way. First we retrieve the entity corresponding to the chemical:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then, if we don't know them by heart, we check out the available properties for chemicals:

```
EntityProperties["Chemical"]
```

This returns a long list of properties. There is one called "element counts" that seems interesting. We try that one:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Although it answers the question as posed, I'm not sure that this is the best approach. There are an infinite number of chemical compounds, and *Mathematica* certainly can't recognise them all. In particular, alloys are often non-stoichiometric and do not really make sense to consider as a single chemical substance: the formula is just a sort of average composition. Even for another fairly simple inorganic chemical, let's say cadmium pyrovanadate, I suspect that this method will fail. (But I wasn't able to test it, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 8):

An attempt at a purely string-processing approach:

```
elem = Alternatives @@ 
   Reverse @ SortBy[StringLength] @ Array[ElementData[#, "Symbol"] &, 112];

chem = StringCases[#, e : elem ~~ n : DigitCharacter ... :> {e, n}] /. "" -> "1" &;

chem @ {"Fe3O4", "CH3Cl"}
```

> ```
> {{{"Fe", "3"}, {"O", "4"}}, {{"C", 1}, {"H", "3"}, {"Cl", "1"}}}
> ```