# How to split text without spaces into list of words?

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, dictionary

What is the best approach to a problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870261/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words) in *Mathematica*?

I can only manage this:

```
 func[stringlist_] := 
   With[{i = 
   Last@Flatten@
   Table[DictionaryLookup[StringTake[#[[2]], n]], {n, 14}]}, {i,
   StringDrop[#[[2]], StringLength@i]}] &@stringlist;
func1[string_] := 
   Rest@NestWhileList[func, {"", # <> CharacterRange["a", "z"]}, 
   Length@Characters@#[[2]] > 26 &][[All, 1]] &@string;


 func1["tableapplechairtablecupboard"]

(*
{"table", "apple", "chair", "table", "cupboard"}
*)
```

with its obvious shortcomings.

## Added

Here is a pre-made file (made from `WordFrequencyData /@ DictionaryLookup[]` - *very slow!!*) incase anyone wanted to make a weighted function:

```
wfd = ToExpression@
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinq321/dictionary/master/values", "List"];
```

*eg* something like [this](https://github.com/martinq321/dictionary/blob/master/mma) (based on @kirma's answer below) can be used to faithfully recreate about 50% of test cases:

```
suggested@StringJoin@removespaces@   
TextSentences[WikipediaData["PageID" -> "5094570", "ArticlePlaintext"]][[1]]

(*
the great wall of china is a series of fortifications made of stone 
brick tamped earth wood and other materials generally built along an 
east to west line across the historical northern borders of china to 
protect the chinese states and empires against the raids and 
invasions of the various nomadic groups of the eurasian steppe
*)
```

though I am sure there are far quicker and more efficient methods.

Comment: Why wouldn't the result be `{"table", "apple", "chair", "table", "cup", "board"}`?

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(3443)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3443/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It looks like a duplicate though the length of the replacement list here may require methods that have a different computational complexity. Have you tested your answer to check it behaves reasonably for dictionary words?

Comment: @Sjoerd defining `altelem = Alternatives @@ DictionaryLookup[];` and using my `f2 @ "tableapplecharitablecupboarding"` appears faster than kirma's `Module`.  (With `Alternatives @@ DictionaryLookup[]` moved outside the latter of course.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard in that case I'll vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple greedy matching can be done as follows: construct a string pattern with longest words first and find words:

```
StringCases["tableapplechairtablecupboard", 
 Alternatives @@ SortBy[DictionaryLookup[], Minus@*StringLength]]

(* {"table", "apple", "chair", "table", "cupboard"} *)
```

Intuitive assumption is that one might use `Longest` to find longest match every time, but it doesn't really seem to work in this case. Note that this variation may end up not matching the whole string as it always chooses the longest match without considering if the rest can match anything in the dictionary.

For all matches one can, for instance, find all word matches using `StringPosition` and then find all non-overlapping complete covers of the string using per-string-position Boolean logic and `SatisfiabilityInstances`:

```
Module[{string, positions},
  string = "tableapplecharitablecupboarding";
  positions = 
   StringPosition[string, Alternatives @@ DictionaryLookup[], 
    Overlaps -> All];
  StringTake[string, Pick[positions, #]] & /@ 
   SatisfiabilityInstances[
    And @@ (BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, Length@positions] @@@ 
       Transpose@
        MapIndexed[Function[{list, index}, # && c @@ index & /@ list],
          Table[#1 <= i <= #2, {i, StringLength@string}] & @@@ 
          positions]), Array[c, Length@positions], All]] // TableForm
```

> $$
> \begin{array}{cccccccc}
>  \text{table} & \text{apple} &
>    \text{char} & \text{it} &
>    \text{able} & \text{cup} &
>    \text{boar} & \text{ding} \\
>  \text{table} & \text{apple} &
>    \text{char} & \text{it} &
>    \text{able} & \text{cup} &
>    \text{boarding} & \text{} \\
>  \text{table} & \text{apple} &
>    \text{charitable} & \text{cup} &
>    \text{boar} & \text{ding} &
>    \text{} & \text{} \\
>  \text{table} & \text{apple} &
>    \text{charitable} & \text{cup} &
>    \text{boarding} & \text{} &
>    \text{} & \text{} \\
> \end{array}
> $$

Note that although `StringPosition` does find "cupboard" as a valid word substring, none of solutions contain it as remaining part of the string can't be split into set of word matches. Thus, "boar", "ding" and "boarding" are only valid endings for a match.

String matching functions do take an additional `IgnoreCase -> True` option, which allows for matching "I" on the above example. Sadly this option also exposes various capitalized non-words, such as "Le", whatever that might be. This problem can occur also with other naturally capitalized words, such as country names.

More procedural approaches to solution search are definitely possible, but in the lines of letting Mma avoid me constructing error-prone explicit algorithms, I've chosen the above approach which converts search to a satisfiability problem.

BTW: can anyone tell why `WordList[]` lacks such words as "is" and "or"? This is the reason for using `DictionaryLookup[]` instead.

Comment: many thanks - great answer :)

Comment: Bounty added for your handling the more complicated problem through methods I do not recall seeing.

Comment: Well this is awkward.  I have temporarily pulled my bounty because it seems I cannot, even as a moderator, close a question with an active bounty.  I wished to close this as a duplicate of [(3443)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3443/121) but I also wish to recognize your unusual and intriguing solution to the problem.  Any suggestion on how I do this?  Sorry for the weirdness. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm open to your suggestions (especially as I'm not entirely certain what you would actually want to happen). :)

Comment: `IncludeInflections -> True` will include "is" but "or"

Comment: "is" and "or" is "Stopwords" in **Mathematica** you should specify the type be "Stopwords".It will include those.

Comment: @yode Intriguing thing about this is that "and" isn't such a word...

Comment: `words=Catenate[WordList[#,Language->"English",IncludeInflections->True]&/@{"KnownWords","Stopwords"}];` will include all words.And if you run `MemberQ[words, "and"]`,it will give `True`.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, why not award the bounty first before closing as a dupe?

Comment: @J.M. I tried to do just that, but it told me I had to wait 23 hours.  Then I tried to close and it told me I couldn't because of a bounty.  By the way do you agree that this is a duplicate?  My `f2` function is directly applicable here but perhaps I am biased.

Comment: "it told me I had to wait 23 hours" - well, that's exactly what you do, @Mr. Wizard; that rule applies to everybody. Anyway, it looks like it can be bountied now; put in the bounty, wait a bit, and you can do the awarding and closure one after another.