# Why the pattern match don't work as expected

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

When I try to figure out [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/119901/how-to-split-text-without-spaces-into-list-of-words),I write such code:

```
words = Catenate[
   WordList[#, Language -> "English", 
      IncludeInflections -> True] & /@ {"KnownWords", "Stopwords"}];
string = StringReplace[
   "What is the best approach to a problem like this in Mathematica?",
    " " -> ""];
StringCases[string, __?(MemberQ[words, ToLowerCase[#]] &)]
```

> {"WhatisthebestapproachtoaproblemlikethisinMathematica"}

But I am confused why I get whole string?What's mistake I have made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You commented on July 6th:

> but I don't understand still why the `?` cannot work totally and give whole `string`.

As MarcoB already quoted:

> In a form such as __?test, every element in the sequence matched by __ must yield True when test is applied.

You can easily see for yourself that this is true.

```
words = {"is", "a", "problem"};

StringCases["What is the best approach to a problem?", __?(MemberQ[words, #] &)]
```

> ```
> {"a", "a", "a", "a"}
> ```

More explicitly we can use `Print` or `Sow` as the test function<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9234/121)</sup> to see exactly which expressions are being tested:

```
Reap[ StringCases["Mathematica", __?Sow] ][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
> "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "h", "h", 
> "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "m", "m", "m", 
> "m", "m", "m", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "i", "i", "i", "c", 
> "c", "a"}
> ```

Observe that:

1. Only single letter strings are ever tested
2. 66 matches are attempted due to every test failing (11 + 10 + 9 + 8 ...)

The first point is actually very useful behavior and I direct you to my own answer [Using a PatternTest versus a Condition for pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1835/using-a-patterntest-versus-a-condition-for-pattern-matching/1852#1852) for additional examples.

The second point is the deleterious consequence of extremely flexible pattern matching used in *Mathematica* which allows the test function itself to be stateful.  I personally feel that there should be a more efficient matching scheme available as an alternative as many uses do not require this level of generality.

Contrast this with [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (short form `/;`)

```
Reap[ StringCases["Mathematica", x__ /; Sow[x]] ][[2, 1]]

{"Mathematica", "Mathematic", "Mathemati", "Mathemat", "Mathema", "Mathem", 
"Mathe", "Math", "Mat", "Ma", "M", "athematica", "athematic", "athemati", 
"athemat", "athema", "athem", "athe", "ath", "at", "a", "thematica", "thematic", 
"themati", "themat", "thema", "them", "the", "th", "t", "hematica", "hematic", 
"hemati", "hemat", "hema", "hem", "he", "h", "ematica", "ematic", "emati", "emat", 
"ema", "em", "e", "matica", "matic", "mati", "mat", "ma", "m", "atica", "atic", 
"ati", "at", "a", "tica", "tic", "ti", "t", "ica", "ic", "i", "ca", "c", "a"}
```

Here we see that every possible alignment is tried, with the entire candidate sequence passed to the test function each time.

Comment: wow,I don't know it before this.

Comment: @yode Thanks for the Accept!

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that your test doesn't work because, according to [the docs for `PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), "In a form such as `__?test`, every element in the sequence matched by `__` must yield `True` when test is applied."

Instead, a [conditional pattern using `/;`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) will work as I think you intended with your definition of the `words` wordlist:

```
StringCases[ToLowerCase@string, word__ /; MemberQ[words, word]]

(* Out: {"what", "is", "thebes", "tap", "pro", "a", "c", "h", "to", "a", "problem", "like", 
         "this", "in", "math", "em", "at", "ic", "a"} *)
```

---

Nevertheless, I'd suggest a bit of cleanup of the word list::

```
words = DeleteDuplicates@
          Select[
            DeleteCases[
              DeleteMissing@words,
              string_ /; StringContainsQ[string, "'" | "-"]
            ],
            StringLength[#] > 1 &
         ];

StringCases[ToLowerCase@string, word__ /; MemberQ[words, word]]

(* Out: {"what", "is", "thebes", "tap", "pro", "to", "problem", "like", \
"this", "in", "math", "em", "at", "ic"} *)
```

... and an easier way to look for all possible matches:

```
StringCases[ToLowerCase@string, words, Overlaps -> True]

(* Out:
 {"what", "ha", "hat", "at", "ti", "tis", "is", "the", "thebe", "thebes", "he", "be", 
  "best", "es", "ta", "tap", "appro", "approach", "pro", "roach", "to", "pro", "problem", 
  "rob", "roble", "em", "ml", "li", "like", "et", "this", "hi", "his", "is", "si", "sin", 
  "in", "nm", "ma", "mat", "math", "at", "the", "them", "thematic", "he", "hem", "hematic", 
  "em", "ma", "mat", "at", "ti", "tic", "ic"}
*)
```

---

These approaches will still run into trouble, though. String matching is greedy by default, which is not always good: for instance, instead of "the best", the underlying sequence is interpreted greedily as ["thebes"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thebes) + "tap".

I really don't know that one could *simply* switch between greedy and lazy matching as appropriate without writing a full-fledged natural language recognition engine. If you came up with anything of the sort, quite a few people would be *very* interested...

Comment: Thanks for your `;`,but I don't understand still why the `?` cannot work totally and give whole `string`.