# Find prefix of list in Association

Tags: pattern-matching, associations, message-coding, character-encoding

I am trying to write some kind of demonstration for coding algorithm (for prefix codes).
I have an Association that contains lists of bits (0s and 1s):

```
<|{"1"} -> "a", {"0", "1"} -> "b", {"0", "0"} -> "c"|>
```

And a list that represents a coded string (which in our example `aabc`):

```
{1,1,0,1,0,0}
```

And Im trying to write a code that searches for a match between a prefix (of any length) from my coded string with a key in the association (without loops).
If I would use a loop I would try to find a prefix in the coded string in increasing length (first look for a match in length 1, then in 2 and so on..).
For now, my goal is to find a match, remove it from the list, and find the next matching. In case I am going wrong with this idea (in the matter of efficiency), I would thank you if you suggest me better ideas.
I have tried to search online and in the forum but without any success. 
Any tip will be appreciated ! 
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but I think you are looking for some sort of prefix tree (trie) search and retrieval and that is discussed in MSE here: ["Can a Trie be implemented efficiently?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/441/34008). Specifically [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/447/34008) should be a good start to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am trying to find a more simple solution for this problem. For now, I'm just trying to find a prefix that exists in the Association.
Maybe a similar parallel problem will be to find the first sub-sequence that is an element in an other list.

Comment: What output do you expect for the example input given?  Do you want to get back "aabc"?

Comment: Yes, this is my final goal.

Comment: This question has to be clarified further.

Comment: @Kobo01 This may work for small `code` but will not be efficient for large `code` especially 30 k. I think @WReach's approach is the best one

Comment: Related: [(3443)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3443/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to use a simple string representation, then `StringReplace` might be adequate for your purpose:

```
decode[s_] := StringReplace[s, {"1" -> "a", "01" -> "b", "00" -> "c"}]

decode["110100"]
(* "aabc" *)

decode["101100101"]
(* "abacab" *)
```

Comment: Works Amazing ! Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

This is probably not highly efficient but I think it does what you describe.

```
asc = <|{1} -> "a", {0, 1} -> "b", {0, 0} -> "c"|>;
code = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0};

rls = KeyValueMap[Append[#, x___] :> (Sow[#2]; {x}) &, asc] // Dispatch;

Reap[code //. rls;][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "a", "b", "c"}
> ```

- Note that I replaced string `"0"` and `"1"` in the Association with integer `0` and `1` for consistency with the coded string (`code`).

Comment: Thank you very much, It worked fine, but took 2 minutes to evalute for a 30kB string...

Answer (score 2):

```
asc = <|{1} -> "a", {0, 1} -> "b", {0, 0} -> "c"|>;

func[assoc_Association, code : {(1 | 0) ..}] := 
Map[assoc[#] &][SequenceCases[code, Alternatives @@ Keys@assoc]];

func[asc,{1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}]
(* {"a", "a", "b", "c"} *)

code = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1};
func[asc,code]
(* {"a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b"} *)
```