# Graph adjacency matrix with unconnected nodes

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I am trying to display a series of 9x9 adjacency matrices which represent directed graphs on a 3x3 grid. The issue I am running up against is this (compounded by that fact that I don't really know how to do anything in Mathematica): only the connected nodes appear, and they do so with a Mathematica-decided geometry. I'd like every point in the adjacency matrix to refer to the same fixed coordinate on the 3x3 grid every time. It seemed that `VertexCoordinates` might work, but it only refers to the vertices that have degree > 0, right?

Insight on how to accomplish this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7183/8

Comment: Yes, `VertexCoordinates` will do what you want.

Comment: @verbeia What about the part about the unconnected nodes?

Comment: I was typing up my answer when you commented :)

Comment: MathTeam, welcome to Mathematica.SE! If you registered your account then any reputation points you get from future questions and answers will be added to those you are getting from this question.

Answer (score 9):

Answers here use table to specify `VertexCoordinates`.  Another way is to use `GridGraph` and extract `VertexCoordinates` from it. It may seem excessive, but it actually requires a bit less code.

```
 AbsoluteOptions[GridGraph[{3, 3}], VertexCoordinates]
```

> VertexCoordinates -> {{1., 1.}, {1., 2.}, {1., 3.}, {2., 
>         1.}, {2., 2.}, {2., 3.}, {3., 1.}, {3., 2.}, {3., 3.}}

You have giant space of 2^81 possible 9x9 matrices. If you need to deal with most of them a nice interactive setup may help. I happen to have some app written already, where you set `AdjacencyMatrix` by mouse clicks. it may come handy, especially when you want to see the relation between `AdjacencyMatrix` and the graph. **To use click on cells in the grid**.

```
Manipulate[
 x = ConstantArray[0, 9 {1, 1}];
 Row[{
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic[tds = Reverse[Transpose[x]];
     MatrixPlot[tds, PlotRangePadding -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
      ImageSize -> {300, 300}, ColorRules -> {1 -> Black, 0 -> None}]
     ],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (pos = Ceiling[
         MousePosition["Graphics"]]; 
       x = ReplacePart[x, pos -> 1 - x[[Sequence @@ pos]]];)}],

   Dynamic@
    AdjacencyGraph[tds, 
     AbsoluteOptions[GridGraph[{3, 3}], VertexCoordinates], 
     ImageSize -> {300, 300}, PlotRange -> {{.5, 3.5}, {.5, 3.5}}, 
     VertexStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.5]], VertexSize -> .2, 
     EdgeStyle -> Thick, DirectedEdges -> True]
   }],
 {pos, ControlType -> None},
 {x, ControlType -> None},
 {tds, ControlType -> None},
 AppearanceElements -> None, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Graph[Range@9, 
 UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[Range@9, 2], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 1], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is an adjacency graph with at least one unconnected node:

```
am = RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[0.1], {9, 9}]

{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Here  are the coordinates if you want to lay those nodes out on a grid.

```
vc = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 3}, {j, 3}], 1]

{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, 
{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}
```

If you use `GraphPlot` rather than `Graph`, the coordinates need to be expressed like this.

```
vcr = Thread[Range[9] -> vc]

{1 -> {1, 1}, 2 -> {1, 2}, 3 -> {1, 3}, 4 -> {2, 1}, 5 -> {2, 2}, 
 6 -> {2, 3}, 7 -> {3, 1}, 8 -> {3, 2}, 9 -> {3, 3}}
```

Here is the case using a `Graph` construct.

```
AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexCoordinates -> vc]
```

[image: Graph]

And here is the case using `GraphPlot`.

```
GraphPlot[am, VertexCoordinateRules -> vcr, SelfLoopStyle -> All]
```

[image]

As you can see, if you specify an adjacency matrix, Mathematica will display the unconnected nodes. You can make the nodes easier to see by using options such as `VertexSize` in `Graph`, and `PlotStyle` or `VertexRenderingFunction` in `GraphPlot`. Here is an example with `GraphPlot` where I have also turned off the self-loop:

```
GraphPlot[am, VertexCoordinateRules -> vcr, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[8]]
```

[image]

The main difference between `Graph` and `GraphPlot` is that the former shows nice curved edges to avoid confusion about whether `{1,3}` is connected to `{3,3}` or `{2,3}`. The option names are all different, too. Which you choose is up to you.