# Proper way to add vertices to an adjacency matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, function-construction

I'm looking for a robust way to add vertices to a graph by modifying its `AdjacencyMatrix`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
addNode[matrix_,in_,out_]:=Module[{mod},
    mod=ArrayPad[matrix,1];
    mod[[1,2]]=1;
    mod[[2,1]]=1;
    mod[[Length@mod,-out]]=1;
    mod[[-out,Length@mod]]=1;
    mod
]
```

This will add a vertex connected to `vertex 1` and another vertex connected to `vertex out`. Notice that I only add 1x1 0's to my matrix. This is because at the moment I only need to add 2 vertices to my graphs.

---

**Examples:**

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

I've tried implementing a similar function that accepts the `in` argument, but I couldn't get it to work properly. It seems as if I have to program special cases for it to work.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want an adjacency matrix as the output or a graph as the output? Or does it not matter?

Comment: @RM I'd prefer an adjacency matrix, since I'll be able to call the function on itself if I need to add more vertices. But in the end, it's not crucial.

Answer (score 10):

There are functions that allow you to add vertices and edges, namely `VertexAdd` and `EdgeAdd`. You can use these to conveniently add vertices and manage connections on the fly. Here's an example that accepts either an `AdjacencyMatrix` or a `Graph` object.

```
Clear@extendGraph
extendGraph[mat_?MatrixQ, vertices_, connect_] :=    
    AdjacencyGraph[mat, GraphLayout -> "SpringEmbedding", 
       VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 5] ~VertexAdd~ vertices ~EdgeAdd~ connect
extendGraph[graph_?GraphQ, vertices_, connect_] := graph ~VertexAdd~ vertices ~EdgeAdd~ connect
```

You can then extend this further to delete edges/vertices using the `EdgeDelete` and `VertexDelete` functions in a similar way.

Here are some example usages:

```
a = {{0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}};
g1 = extendGraph[a, {5, 6}, {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}]
```

[image]

```
g2 = extendGraph[g1, {7, 8}, {7 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}]
```

[image]

Use `AdjacencyMatrix` on the above graphs to get the matrix (although, it is not necessary, since my definition allows you to use it again on the graph itself)

```
AdjacencyMatrix@g2 // Normal
(* {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
    {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 
    {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I didn't know about `VertexAdd` and `EdgeAdd`.

Answer (score 4):

I answered a similar question before using interactive solution in [**this example**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/graph-adjacency-matrix-with-unconnected-nodes/7264#7264). To construct a basic function you could use `EdgeList`:

```
f[m_, v1_, v2_] := AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[EdgeList[AdjacencyGraph[m, 
                   DirectedEdges -> False]]~Join~{v1 \[UndirectedEdge] v2}]]
```

Here how it works. If you start from a matrix:

```
m = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, 
     {1, 0, 1, 1}, 
     {1, 1, 0, 1}, 
     {0, 1, 1, 0}};
```

this is what you will get:

```
f[m, 4, 5] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

These are the graphs:

```
AdjacencyGraph /@ {m, %}
```

[image]

Now if you want to add a few vertexes at a time you could modify your function like:

```
g[m_, l_] := AdjacencyMatrix[Graph[EdgeList[AdjacencyGraph[m, 
             DirectedEdges -> False]]~Join~(UndirectedEdge @@@ l)]]
```

Don't for get that labels can be pretty arbitrary and new vertexes can be disconnected from original graph - it still will work:

```
g[m, {{4, 5}, {5, "CAT"}, {"DOG", "BIRD"}}] // Normal // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
AdjacencyGraph /@ {m, %}
```

[image]