# Plotting a network or a graph with given coordinates for vertices

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I'm new to *Mathematica* yet have coded a lot in MATLAB. Currently I'm working on a network simulation. My model is implemented in MATLAB, but I need to port it to *Mathematica*.

**Here is my question**:

Given a graph `g` and coordinates `x` and `y` for each node. I want to plot the network with nodes at the corresponding coordinates. How can this be done?

In case you are also used to MATLAB, there is the function [`gplot`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/gplot.html), which does the job. Is there a similar plotting function in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Maybe it's a case for `AdjacencyMatrix[]`. Please take a look at [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7250/graph-adjacency-matrix-with-unconnected-nodes).

Comment: Or `GraphPlot`, using `VertexCoordinateRules` to specifiy coordinates? (See Documentation Center)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you simulating?  Unfortunately neither Mathematica not MATLAB are great at simulations (they're too slow), but Mma is great for analysis and visualization.

Comment: The latter is the reason I'm switching to Mathematica. The model I'm working is of theoretical interest only: I want to see, whether there will be segregation in different types of dynamic networks.

Comment: @user8115 If you already have your simulation code in MATLAB and just want to do the analysis/visualization in Mathematica, you can consider using [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) (shameless self promotion ;-)  Note: MATLink has good support for sparse arrays, in case you represent graphs using those.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I think this comment is an oversimplification. I have coded simulations in Mathematica that are quite close to the speed in C, and I used much less time to get there than the C code.

Comment: @ruebenko Well I do prefer Mathematica when I can use it.  My experience may have to do with the kinds of problems I was using it for.  [This is one problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27300/12) for which it is reasonable to consider Mathematica, yet the difference in my experience tends to be very large between C and Mma (Mma is not necessarily slow but I think C will be much faster for that program).  When one can use either `Compile` or work with matrix operations on large matrices, then I think Mma will be more competitive (especially in the latter case).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example:

```
Graph[{1, 2}, {1 <-> 2}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]
```

Pass the vertex list, edge list, and VertexCoordinates -> vertexCoordinateList to Graph. The coordinate list is in the same order as the vertex list.

Comment: What if the coordinate list is unordered?For example, a set of circular coordinates that are out of order.