# Pasting monospaced text into Mathematica notebook destroys aligment

Tags: formatting, text, fonts, display

I drew the little ASCII-art electronics schema below in vim.

When i try to paste it into a Mathematica notebook, with:

A) A code cell
   B) A monospaced font (Courier New)

Mathematica insists on destroying the vertical aligment.

Here is what it looks like in vim:
[image]

And here's what it looks like in Mathematica:

[image]

Even worse, when I try to re-align things by hand
in the notebook, the end result looks very bad (note
the misaligned vertical bars on the right hand side)

[image]

For something so simple to be so hard ... I must
be missing something glaringly obvious.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you pasting text into a code cell?  Code cells automatically format their contents.  You'll never get it to look right.  Perhaps you want to `Import` the file as a `String`?

Comment: Mathematica notebook really needs a verbatim cell and/or verbatim wrapper, where one can write Verbatim[" string "] and the content will show as is. No formating. As in Latex's verbatim environment http://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim, can be used for comments in code as well. Try making free form comments using (* *) and you'll see how hard it is to align the comments the way you want with the code.

Comment: As a side note, if you're interested more in drawing circuits than text alignment, you might find these useful: [Circuit drawing in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/circuit-drawing-in-mathematica) and
[Graph layout on a grid](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5430/graph-layout-on-a-grid)

Comment: @MichaelE2 : I tried a text cell. Same problem.

Comment: @Kuba: Sure, I could do a graphics, but it's really not as fast as ASCII art, and all I need here is a quick and dirty schema to help me make sense of the equations.

Comment: It works for me on my own example.  But it's cool you found a solution.  You should post it as answer to your own question, by the way.

Comment: maybe i'm being an idiot by bringing this up, but you can do some basic vector editing (by hand) in Mathematica

Comment: The basic problem is that whitespace is not (or only rarely) significant in *Mathematica*, so in anything that counts as code, spacing is usually freely adjusted to improve legibility, to differentiate sigils from other sequences of characters, and so on. Not so for arbitrary strings, as you found. This can probably be changed in the stylesheet, but I have no experience with stylesheet editing personally. To be honest, not that it helps with this question, I'd probably draw the circuit in LTspice. Not only is it quicker, you can also simulate it as well if you want to.

Comment: Are you really pasting that into a *Code* cell or an *Input* cell?  Code cells don't reformat the text, only Input cells do.  Try pasting into an actual Code cell.  Use Window -> Show Toolbar, select the cell bracket, change the cell style to "Code".  Or insert a new cell using Alt-8 (Command-8 on Mac).

Comment: @Oleksandr : I actually designed the circuit in LTSpice in the first place. The reason I want an ASCII version of the circuit in Mathematica is because LTSpice does not let you easily annotate a circuit with node labels and branch orientations. LTSpice also does not solve symbolic system of equations: the point is to have both circuit and symbolic solutions inside Mathematica. And like I mentioned before, it is *way* faster to edit ASCII art than editing a drawn diagram.

Comment: @OleksandrR. With regards to the alleged "improving legibility" part, without trying to be snarky here, Mathematica does the *exact* opposite of the stated goal here. I'm all for smart, automated formatting, as long as it can be put to rest when it does dumb things.

Answer (score 12):

The *Program* style is purpose-built for this sort of thing:

[image: cell using program style]

If you do not like the look of the bars above and below the cell, you can remove them by selecting the cell and changing the *CellFrame* option in the *Option Inspector*:

[image: cell with bars removed]

Answer (score 3):

I seem to have found a solution, kind of convoluted,
and not entirely sure why it works.

- Create a cell
- Cell -> Convert To -> Raw Input Form
- Open a comment in the cell
- Paste the ASCII art
- Close comment

This is what it looks like now:

[image]