# Performance tuning for game solving (peg solitaire | senku)

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

There's a game I saw at a friend's yesterday, that I often see at people's homes, but never for enough time to think on it too hard. It's called [peg solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire) (thanks @R.M).
So I came home and I wanted to find a solution in Mathematica, so I did the following

First, some visual functions. The game consists of a board with some slots that can either have a piece on it (black dot in this visual representation) or be empty (white dot)

```
empty=Circle[{0,0},0.3];
filled=Disk[{0, 0}, 0.3];

plotBoard[tab_]:=Graphics[GeometricTransformation[#1,TranslationTransform/@
     Position[tab, #2]]&@@@{{empty, 0},{filled, 1}}, ImageSize->Small]
```

The starting board is the following.

```
tableroStart=({
 {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
 {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
 {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}
});
```

-1 is used to represent places where there can't be any pieces. 0 for empty slots. 1 for slots with a piece on it.

So,

```
plotBoard[tableroStart] // Framed
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rules: Given a board such as the previous one, you can only move by "taking" a single piece, jumping over it. So, you take a piece, you choose one of the 4 straight directions, you jump over the adjacent piece and fall in an empty slot. The game is won by having only one last piece on the board. So, in the starting board, there are 4 possible moves, all symmetrical.

In this code, moves are represented by rules, so, `{3, 4}->{3, 6}` represents a move of
the piece in coordinates `{3, 4}`, to coordinates `{3, 6}`, jumping over the piece at `{3, 5}` and taking it out of the board.

So, let's start programming.

This finds the possible moves towards some specified zero position

```
findMovesZero[tab_,pos_List]:=pos+#&/@(Join[#, Reverse/@#]&[Thread@{{0, 1, 3, 4}, 2}])//
Extract[ArrayPad[tab, 2],#]&//
Pick[{pos-{2, 0}, pos+{2, 0}, pos-{0, 2}, pos+{0, 2}},UnitStep[Total/@Partition[
#, 2]-2], 1]->pos&//Thread[#, List, 1]&
```

Lists all the possible moves given a board tab

```
i:findMoves[tab_]:=i=Flatten[#, 1]&[findMovesZero[tab, #]&/@Position[tab, 0]]
```

Given the board `tab`, makes the move

```
makeMove[tab_, posFrom_->posTo_]:=ReplacePart[tab , {posFrom->0, Mean[{posFrom, posTo}]->0,posTo->1}];
```

Now, the solving function

```
(* solve, given a board tab, returns a list of subsequent moves to win, or $Failed *)
(* markTab is recursive. If a board is a success, marks it with $Success and makes all subsequent markTab calls return $NotNecessary *)
(* If a board is not a success and doesn't have any more moves, returns $Failed. If it has moves, it just calls itself on every board,
saving the move made in the head of the new boards. I know, weird *)
Module[{$Success,$NotNecessary, parseSol, $guard, markTab},

markTab[tab_/;Count[tab, 1, {2}]===1]:=$Success/;!($guard=False)/;$guard;
i:markTab[tab_]:=With[{moves=findMoves[tab]},(i=If[moves==={}, $Failed,(#[markTab@makeMove[tab, #]]&/@moves)])]/;$guard;
markTab[tab_]/;!$guard:=$NotNecessary;

(* parseSol converts the tree returned by markTab into the list of moves until $Success, or in $Failed *)
parseSol[sol_]/;FreeQ[{sol}, $Success]:=$Failed;
parseSol[sol_]:=sol[[Apply[Sequence,#;;#&/@First@Position[sol, $Success]]]]//#/.r_Rule:>Null/;(Sow[r];False)&//Reap//#[[2, 1]]&;

solve[tab_]:=Block[{$guard=True},parseSol@markTab@tab];
]
```

Solution visualization function

```
plotSolution[tablero_, moves_]:=
MapIndexed[Show[plotBoard[#1], Epilog->{Red,Dashed,Arrow[List@@First@moves[[#2]]]}]&, Rest@FoldList[makeMove[#, #2]&,tablero,moves]]//
Prepend[#, plotBoard[tablero]]&//Grid[Partition[#, 4, 4, 1, Null], Frame->All]&

(* Solves and plots *)
solveNplot = With[{sol=solve[#]},If[sol===$Failed, $Failed, plotSolution[#, sol]]]&;
```

In action:

```
solveNplot[( {
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1},
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}
  } )]
```

returns, after about a min's though,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, the question is. How can we make it efficient enough so it can do the trick for an almost filled board like `tableroStart`?

The first move is actually always the same let alone symmetries so we could start a move ahead

Comment: I love this game! It's called [peg solitaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire). I used to play it very often as a kid. The Wikipedia link also provides the shortest solution to the game.

Comment: @R.M, SPOILER ALERT, I won't open the link! Shouldn't all solutions be equally short since you take no more and no less than one piece out every move?

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'move' and if you choose the wrong path in the decision tree. In the standard game, you can take several pieces in one move. For example, if you had a row `1 1 0 1 0 1 0`, then _you_ move the first element to the third position (at which point it can be captured by another piece from above or below). On the other hand, you could keep moving, resulting in `0 0 0 0 0 0 1` (and continue down/up and then back if the row position permits it).

Comment: Shouldn't the final peg end up in the central hole?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I trust you more than my friend in this, so probably yes. This is just what my friend told me. It could be a nice follow-up

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Preamble

Here is my first stab at it. This will not be the fastest possible solution (I hope to add some faster ones later), but even it will have no problems with your boards, including the full one you started with.

Before we dive into code, I will list the prerequisites for fast code in this case:

- Right choice of data structures
- Avoiding symbolic Mathematica overhead, which, sorry to say it, is just huge
- Avoiding copying in favor of direct modifications

#### Code

Reproducing @Rojo's visualization functions to make this self-contained:

```
empty = Circle[{0, 0}, 0.3];
filled = Disk[{0, 0}, 0.3]; 

plotBoard[tab_] := 
  Graphics[GeometricTransformation[#1, 
      TranslationTransform /@ Position[tab, #2]] & @@@ 
        {{empty, 0}, {filled, 1}}, ImageSize -> Small]
```

I will start with your test board:

```
start = 
{
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1}, 
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}, 
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}, 
   {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1}
}
```

First comes the optimized compiled function to find all possible steps for a given board:

```
getStepsC = 
 Compile[{{board, _Integer, 2}},
  Module[{black = Table[{0, 0}, {Length[board]^2}], bctr = 0, i, j,
     steps = Table[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {Length[board]^2}], stepCtr = 0, 
     next, nnext
   },
   Do[
     If[board[[i, j]] == 1, black[[++bctr]] = {i, j}], 
     {i, 1,Length[board]}, {j, 1, Length[board]}
   ];
   black = Take[black, bctr];
   Do[
     Do[
       next = pos + st;
       nnext = pos + 2*st;
       If[board[[next[[1]], next[[2]]]] == 1 && 
            board[[nnext[[1]], nnext[[2]]]] == 0,
         steps[[++stepCtr]] = {pos, nnext}
       ],
       {st, {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}, 
         {-1,0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}}}
     ], 
     {pos, black}
   ];
   Take[steps, stepCtr]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
 ];
```

This function is expecting the board padded with `-1`-s, so that we don't have to check that the point belongs to the board. It will therefore also return cooridinates shifted by 1. It returns a list of sublists of starting and ending points for possible steps. Here is an example:

```
getStepsC[ArrayPad[start, 1, -1]]
```

> ```
>   {{{2, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 6}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 6}}, {{2, 5}, {4, 5}}, 
>     {{2, 5}, {4, 7}}, {{4, 2}, {6, 4}}, {{4, 2}, {4, 4}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 4}}, 
>     {{6, 2}, {6, 4}}, {{6, 2}, {4, 4}}, {{8,4}, {6, 6}}, {{8, 4}, {6, 4}}, 
>     {{8, 5}, {6, 7}}, {{8, 5}, {6, 5}}, {{8, 6}, {6, 6}}, {{8, 6}, {6, 4}}}
> ```

Here is a function which helps to visualize all possible steps:

```
ClearAll[showPossibleSteps];
showPossibleSteps[brd_] :=
  Show[plotBoard[brd], 
     Epilog -> 
      Map[{Red, Dashed, Arrow[# - {1, 1}]} &, 
        getStepsC[ArrayPad[brd, 1, -1]]]]
```

It pads the board with `-1`-s and subtracts `1` from both coordinates for the resulting steps. Using it, we get:

```
showPossibleSteps[start]
```

[image]

Next comes the main recursive function:

```
Clear[makeStep];
makeStep[steps : {step : {st_, end_}, prev_}, memoQ : (True | False) : False] :=
 Module[{nblacks},
    nblacks := Total@Clip[Flatten@board, {0, 1}];
    If[nblacks == 1, Throw[steps, "Win"]];
    If[memoQ && visited[board],
       Return[]
    ];
    board[[st[[1]], st[[2]]]] = 
         board[[(st[[1]] + end[[1]])/2, (st[[2]] + end[[2]])/2]] = 0;
    board[[end[[1]], end[[2]]]] = 1;
    If[nblacks == 1, Throw[steps, "Win"]];
    Do[makeStep[{new, steps}, memoQ], {new, getStepsC[board]}];
    If[memoQ, visited[board] = True];
    board[[st[[1]], st[[2]]]] = 
      board[[(st[[1]] + end[[1]])/2, (st[[2]] + end[[2]])/2]] = 1;
    board[[end[[1]], end[[2]]]] = 0;
 ];

 makeStep[___] := Throw[$Failed];
```

Few notes here: first, the `board` variable is not local to the body of `makeStep` (it is a global variable). Second, memoization can be switched on and off by the `memoQ` flag, and the related hash-table `visited` is also global. The above function is intended to be driven by the main one, not to be used in isolation. Last, note that the history of the previous steps is recorded in the linked list, which is an efficient way of doing this.

The way the function works is similarly to the @Rojo's code, but instead of collecting entire tree and then traversing it, it throws an exception at run-time as soon as the solution is found, and communicates the collected list of previous step via this exception. This allows the code to be memory-efficient.

Now, the main function:

```
Clear[getSolution];
getSolution[brd_, memoQ : (True | False) : False] :=
  Block[{board = Developer`ToPackedArray@ArrayPad[brd, 1, -1], visited},
     visited[_] = False;
     Catch[
        Do[makeStep[{new, {}}, memoQ], {new, getStepsC[board]}], 
        "Win"
     ]
  ];
```

Here are functions used for visualization:

```
ClearAll[showBoardStep];
showBoardStep[brd_, step_] :=
   Show[plotBoard[brd], Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Arrow[step]}];

ClearAll[toPlainListOfSteps];
toPlainListOfSteps[stepsLinkedList_] :=
  Reverse@
    Reap[
       NestWhile[(Sow[First@# - {1, 1}]; Last[#]) &, 
           stepsLinkedList, # =!= {} &]
    ][[2, 1]];

ClearAll[showSolution];
showSolution[startBoard_, stepsLinkedList_] :=
  Module[{b = startBoard},
    Grid[Partition[#, 4, 4, 1, Null], Frame -> All] &@
      MapAt[plotBoard, #, 1] &@
        FoldList[
           With[{st = #2[[1]], end = #2[[2]]},
              b[[st[[1]], st[[2]]]] = 
                 b[[(st[[1]] + end[[1]])/2, (st[[2]] + end[[2]])/2]] = 0;
              b[[end[[1]], end[[2]]]] = 1;
              showBoardStep[b, #2]] &, 
           b, 
           toPlainListOfSteps[stepsLinkedList]]];
```

What happens here is that I convert the linked list of steps to a plain list, and perform the relevant transformations on the board.

#### Results and benchmarks

First, the test board, with and without the memoization:

```
getSolution[start]//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.0585938,
>        {{{4,2},{4,4}},{{{4,5},{4,3}},{{{6,3},{4,5}},{{{7,4},{5,4}},
>        {{{8,6},{6,4}},<<1>>}}}}}
>    }
> ```

```
(stepList = getSolution[start,True])//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.0419922,
>        {{{4,2},{4,4}},{{{4,5},{4,3}},{{{6,3},{4,5}},{{{7,4},{5,4}},
>        {{{8,6},{6,4}},<<1>>}}}}}
>    }
> ```

Note that the steps are reversed (last steps are shown first), and coordinates are shifted by 1. If you use

```
showSolution[start, stepList]
```

you get a sequence similar to what is displayed in the question.

Note that it only took a small fraction of a second to get the result (as opposed to a minute cited by @Rojo). Note also that memoization helped, but not dramatically so.

Now, the real deal:

```
(stepList0 = getSolution[tableroStart]);//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {18.7744141,Null}
> ```

```
(stepList = getSolution[tableroStart,True])//Short//AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
>  {2.0517578,{{{6,2},{6,4}},{{{6,5},{6,3}},{{{6,7},{6,5}},
>        {{{8,6},{6,6}},{{{8,4},{8,6}},<<1>>}}}}}}
> ```

Here memoization helps a great deal - we get an order of magnitude speedup. And here are the steps:

```
showSolution[tableroStart, stepList]
```

[image]

#### Conclusions

This problem makes for a great case study, and is a very nice vehicle to study and analyze various performance issues as they reflect themselves in Mathematica. I have presented a straightforward (conceptually) implementation, whose main merit is not that the algorithm is particularly clever, but that it avoids some (but not all) serious performance pitfalls. Some other performance hits seem to be unavoidable, particularly those related to the top-level code being slow (`makeStep` function). This would have been different had `Compile` supported pass-by-reference and hash-tables (so that `makeStep` could be efficiently compiled).

As I said, this is not the fastest method, and I intend to add faster code later, but it illustrates main points. Note that the solution is essentially the same (conceptually) as what @Rojo did (except that I don't construct the full tree). What is really different is that frequent operations such as search for next steps are heavily optimized here (they take the most time), and also, I win big by mutating the board in place rather than copy it in the recursive invocations of `makeStep`. The result is a 3 orders of magnitude speed-up, and perhaps the solution has different computational complexity in general (although this is not yet clear to me).

**Coming soon**: Java port of this solution, prototyped entirely in Mathematica, which is another 20-30 times faster (according to my benchmarks).

Comment: I don't understand this yet but +1 in confidence.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :)

Comment: +1. I'll dig into this soon, I was hoping you would get tempted by the performance tuning tag and come teach us, hehe. Anyway, it would probably be faster if you avoided the diagonal jumps, right?

Comment: @Rojo Somehow I wasn't reading your rules carefully enough, and assumed diagonal jumps are permitted. Which would be faster, hard to say, because diagonal jumps increase not only the number of all paths but also the number of valid solutions. But. generally, I think you are right. The modification to rule them out is trivial - one just has to remove half of the list of possible moves which in iterated over in the inner `Do` in the compiled function.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I am still surprised with how much faster your solution to the peg solitaire question is... I thought that given that mine also stops searching when it has found a solution, there wouldn't be a MMA solution 3 orders of magnitude faster! If that's all unnecessary symbolic overhead that I just threw out there without compunction, I'll have to start writing some mental notes

Comment: @Rojo One of the problematic things with top-level Mma code is that it is not just slow in a few places, it is slow *by default*, by the very nature of symbolic M evaluation. So, if you have 3 places where you lose 10 times in each, you may be unlucky if they combine, and lose 1000 times in performance. In this particular case, I removed 2 major bottlenecks, both related to individual board checks: made the function producing new steps compiled and very fast, and used in-place board modifications to avoid copying the board at every step. They together were responsible for the 1000 fold ...

Comment: @Rojo ... speedup. But one last bottleneck in this algorithm - the top-level code for `nextStep` - I could not remove, since `Compile` can not really handle pass-by-reference. But wait, Java code is on the way (I have it ready for quite a while now), it is 20-30 times faster still :-). By the way, the votes on this question / answers is very illustrative regarding the short question life / attention span (which is a consequence of the SE model),  but that's an entirely different story :-).

Comment: @Rojo Regarding the speed difference which you found so surprising, very similar story happened for my [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/using-mathematicas-graph-functions-to-cheat-at-boggle/5394#5394) to the Boggle question - you can see the comment of the OP who was also surprised that using trie (right choice of data structures) was more important than controlling the number of solutions. Think about all this as a tree. We do want to reduce the number of branches, but if the leaves are very heavy, they matter more.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, thanks, I'll be digging into the bottlenecks soon to get the juice out of this question. Btw, as I told MrWizard earlier, check out my edit on the 2K question. I think perhaps you'll find it interesting

Comment: @Rojo Man, that's insane! This is one of the most elegant pieces of M code I ever saw! I would vote many times if I could.

Comment: Thanks! That means a lot coming from someone who has seen so much MMA code and has elephant memory. I just tuned it a little bit more

Answer (score 8):

Reader Beware: This does not solve the problem

I started trying to use graphs instead of lists with the idea of using isomorphisms to discard solution branches already explored.

I got a working solution, but too heavy to be used for the full problem. I was not able to find a way for *efficiently* identifying isomorphic states and so my solution is a recursive hog.

Anyway, as I am not going to spend more time with it for a while, I decided to post the code here, for the benefit of others trying *the graph way*.

Here it is:

```
(* manufacture vertex positions :) *)
places = MaxFilter[CrossMatrix[3], 1];
placesPos = Position[places, 1];
mPos = Max@placesPos;
pegNum = Length@placesPos;
g = Graph[Array[# &, pegNum], {}, VertexCoordinates -> placesPos, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];

(*Allowable jumps *)

j1 = Select[Flatten[Table[Intersection[{{k, i}, {k, i + 1}, {k, i + 2}}, placesPos], 
           {k, mPos}, {i, mPos}], 1], Length@# == 3 &];
j2 = Select[Flatten[Table[Intersection[{{k, i}, {k + 1, i}, {k + 2, i}}, placesPos], 
           {k, mPos}, {i, mPos}], 1], Length@# == 3 &];
th = Thread[IntegerPart /@ PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ VertexList[g] -> VertexList[g]];
j = Union[j1, j2] /. th;
jumps = UndirectedEdge @@@ (j[[All, {1, 3}]]);

(*test drive graph*)
g1 = Graph[Table[i, {i, pegNum}], jumps, VertexCoordinates -> placesPos, 
         VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10];
(*jump over what vertex for each transition *)
(PropertyValue[{g1, #[[1]]}, "jOver"] = #[[2]]) & /@ Transpose[{jumps, j[[All, 2]]}];
(*Initially Occupied Vertex stock  Replace "7" with pegNum for a looong wait*)
(PropertyValue[{g1, #[[1]]}, "occ"] = #[[2]]) & /@ Table[{i, If[i <= 7, True, False]}, {i, pegNum}];

(*Utility funcs*)
SetAttributes[{freeV, jOver, pMoves, seeBoard, doMove, ret},  HoldFirst];
freeV[g_, x_] := ! PropertyValue[{g, x}, "occ"]; (*is the vertex free?*)
jOver[x_UndirectedEdge] := PropertyValue[{g1, x}, "jOver"]; (*Which vertex to jump over?*)
(*Select Possible moves at a certain graph state*)
pMoves[g_] := Select[jumps, ((freeV[g, #[[1]]]) != freeV[g, #[[2]]]) && (! freeV[g, jOver[#]]) &];
(*Utility for drawing  occupancy*)
seeBoard[g_] := Module[{}, 
    vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] :=If[freeV[g, name], {Blue, #}, {Red, #}] &@ Disk[{xc, yc}, Min@{w, h}];
       Graph[Table[i, {i, pegNum}], jumps, VertexCoordinates -> placesPos,
            VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 10, VertexShapeFunction -> vf, Frame -> True]];
(*perform a move> blank jOver vertex and traslate original*)
(*Note that we can't distinguish source & destination*)
(* Does not check if initial conditions are met*)
doMove[g_, x_UndirectedEdge] :=
  (PropertyValue[{g, x[[1]]}, "occ"] = !PropertyValue[{g, x[[1]]}, "occ"];
   PropertyValue[{g, x[[2]]}, "occ"] = !PropertyValue[{g, x[[2]]}, "occ"];
   PropertyValue[{g, jOver[x]}, "occ"] = False;);
(*Test move*)
(*seeBoard[g1]
doMove[g1,1\[UndirectedEdge]9];*)
seeBoard[g1]
(*solving function*)
ret[g_, m_] := Module[{c := g}, 
              If[(pMoves[g] != {}), 
                Module[{k = c}, (doMove[k, #]; ret[k, Append[m, #]])] & /@  pMoves[g]]; Sow[m]];
(*Check results. We dont distinguish between a->b and b->a yet!*)
l = (Reap@ret[g1, {}])[[2, 1]];
Length@l
TableForm@Select[l, (Length@# == (Max@(Length /@ l))) &]
```

Comment: I thought about isomorphisms too. With the four-fold rotation symmetry of the starting position that would be a natural thing to do. I didn't go that way because it is my intuition that later on in the combinatorial explosion of this game symmetry will be less prominent and you don't gain sufficiently by pruning them. I may be wrong there.

Comment: @Sjoerd And there there are also reflection symmetries ...

Comment: @Sjoerd I think the [Dihedral group D4/8](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8) is a good candidate

Comment: There's also a deeper symmetry: the game is reversible and the roles of spaces and pieces can be reversed, too.