# Efficient backtracking with Mathematica

Tags: programming, algorithm, recursion, guidelines

> Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some computational problem, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons each partial candidate *c* ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that *c* cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution. (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking))

In pseudo-code, a backtracking algorithm looks something like this:

```
 procedure bt(c)
   if reject(P,c) then return
   if accept(P,c) then output(P,c)
   s ← first(P,c)
   while s ≠ Λ do
     bt(s)
     s ← next(P,s)
```

Here,

1. `root(P)`: return the partial candidate at the root of the search
    tree.
2. `reject(P,c)`: return `true` only if the partial candidate `c` is not
    worth completing.
3. `accept(P,c)`: return `true` if `c` is a solution of `P`, and `false`
    otherwise.
4. `first(P,c)`: generate the first extension of candidate `c`.
5. `next(P,s)`: generate the next alternative extension of a candidate,
    after the extension `s`.
6. `output(P,c)`: use the solution `c` of `P`, as appropriate to the
    application.

The backtracking algorithm then starts with the call `bt(root(P))`.

I'm trying to program this as efficiently as possible in Mathematica. I have already coded the pertinent `root`, `reject`, `accept`, `first`, and `next` functions. Since I only need to obtain one solution, I am doing the `output` through a `Throw`, `Catch` combo.

Given that one has the basic logic of `root`, `reject`, ..., already coded, are there alternative ways to program the backtracking loop (procedure `bt` above) in Mathematica?

What I have in mind is a substitution of `while` with something more Mathematica friendly, such as `Fold` or `Map`, but I have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: It's hard to give a general solution for such a generic description. I do something similar to this in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5392/5) to the Boggle question, where I start down a node and evaluate the partial candidates  and reject the subtree if the partial candidate will never lead to a useful solution. I do this with using `Condition`. See the functions `proceedQ` and `sowWord` for the equivalents of `reject/accept` and `output` respectively. `first/next` are implemented via recursion...

Comment: @R.M I think I cannot use what you suggest. I cannot store my backtrack tree in a graph (or an analogue like an adjacency matrix) because it is huge. Imagine beginning a scan of chess positions by storing a graph will all the possible positions. Not possible. I haven't read Leonid's enormous answer to the question you reference, but if it also stores a representation of the search space, I can't use it.

Comment: Also, I don't want a general solution. Just an alternative solution. I understand that to design a truly efficient code you would have to see my `first`, `reject`, and so on. But they are quite convoluted and specific. I just need alternative ways to program the `bt` procedure. I hope it'll give me ideas to make my program more efficient.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that it was an answer... I merely meant that you could look at that (and Leonid's answer) for possible ideas on how to approach it.

Comment: ok ok. See I did +1 your comment. I thought it was useful.

Comment: Anything doable by procedural programming can be done recursively (and functionally). And then the symmetry comes to an end. Iterative (procedural) programming is the way to go if you have severe memory constraints. [No le pidas peras al olmo](http://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/peras+al+olmo.html)

Comment: In fact, that Boggle problem illustrates the comment of @R.M. well, since our solutions are conceptually close but the different choice of data structures leads to very different performance. Another such example is the [Peg Solitaire](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/performance-tuning-for-game-solving-peg-solitaire) problem, where there are also two solutions currently posted (the original OP's one and mine), and again, being conceptually the same, they are 3 orders of magnitude different performance-wise. So, it depends on the problem, *particularly* so in Mathematica.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Rethinking the Q. Letting aside the space and time conditioning, I believe a general pattern for the backtracking algorithm could be the "most" correct answer to this question. And perhaps the most beneficial for future visitors, with all the caveats you already wrote. What do you think?

Comment: @belisarius I think we need to accumulate more non-trivial problems solved by some variant of backtracking, and then see if we have some common implementation patterns (e.g. using linked lists + recursion, etc). I don't believe that we can totally separate the backtracking pattern from implementation in Mathematica, given that efficiency is always one of the main goals, and (particularly in Mathematica) it depends drastically on implementation details (such as the choice of data structures, etc).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ok. I am posting Scrabble, checkers, chess, ... wait ... I'd rather not post the chess question :D

Comment: Given that your method is recursive, I do not see how it avoids storage similar to that incurred from explicit data structures and iteration. Internally there has to be a subroutine stack...

Comment: I just discovered the `guidelines` tag and I think it goes with this question. @DanielLichtblau I do not need to store all the possible chess positions to search them. I just need methods that given a chess position, return other positions to explore (`next` and `first`) in an organized fashion.

Comment: @belisarius I don't care about memory (for the moment). What is giving me trouble is the **time**.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I was only asking for alternative ways to program the `bt` loop, given that the functions `next`, `first`, and so on, satisfying the descriptions given in the question, are coded and ready to be called. I am not ambitious enough to pursue anything more general than that.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin btw, I am reading your book :)

Answer (score 8):

Backtracking is never efficient so I would suggest always using C for this. However if you must do this in mathematica, here is an example of the generalized backtrack algorithm (as taken almost literally from the `` Combinatorica` `` package's  `Backtrack` function) specifically applied to graph coloring:

```
backtrack[space_List, partialQ_, solutionQ_, flag_: 1] := 
 Module[{n = Length[space], all = {}, done, index, v = 2, solution},
    index = Prepend[Table[0, {n - 1}], 1];
    Monitor[While[v > 0,
            done = False;
            While[! done && (index[[v]] < Length[space[[v]]]),
                   index[[v]]++;
                   done = partialQ[Solution[space, index, v]];
                        ];
            If[done, v++, index[[v--]] = 0];
            If[v > n,
                solution = Solution[space, index, n];
                If[solutionQ[solution], 
                    If[SameQ[flag, All],
                            AppendTo[all, solution],
                            all = solution; v = 0;
                            ]
                     ]
                  v--;
                ]
        ], index];
    all
  ]


Solution[space_List, index_List, count_Integer] :=

  Module[{i}, Table[space[[i, index[[i]]]], {i, count}]];

ProperColorQ[color_List] := {} == 
   Cases[EdgeList[gr] /. Thread[Range[Length[color]] -> color], 
    x_ \[UndirectedEdge] x_, \[Infinity], 1];


Ccoloring[c_Integer, g_Graph] :=

 Module[{coloring, x, v = Length[VertexList[g]]},
  coloring = backtrack[Join[{{1}}, Table[Range[c], {i, v - 1}]],
    ({} == 
       Cases[EdgeList[g] /. Thread[Range[Length[#]] -> #], 
        x_ \[UndirectedEdge] x_, \[Infinity], 1]) &,
    ({} == 
       Cases[EdgeList[g] /. Thread[Range[Length[#]] -> #], 
        x_ \[UndirectedEdge] x_, \[Infinity], 1]) &,
    One]
  ]

chromaticNumber[g_Graph /; ConnectedGraphQ[g]] :=
 Module[{c, i = 2},
  c = Ccoloring[i, gr];
  While[c == {}, c = Ccoloring[i, gr]; i++];
  {i - 1,
   Graph[EdgeList[g],
    VertexLabels -> 
     Table[i -> Placed[c[[i]], Center], {i, Length[VertexList[g]]}], 
    VertexStyle -> 
     Thread[Range[Length[VertexList[g]]] -> 
       Hue /@ Rescale[c, {0, 0.9}]]]}
  ]


gr = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[13, 0.5], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
chromaticNumber[gr] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: Thanks. In your experience, how much faster can C be compared to Mathematica when doing backtraking?

Comment: If your code references someone else's, it's worth mentioning, so I edited in the reference