# Why is NeighborhoodGraph so slow?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, performance-tuning

To get neighboring vertices I first tried:

```
gg = GridGraph[{10, 10, 10, 10}];
VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[gg, 1, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.539308, {1, 2, 11, 101, 1001}}

But that is really slow. This is much faster and still uses the new `Graph` package:

```
Union[VertexInComponent[gg, 1, 1], VertexOutComponent[gg, 1, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000172, {1, 2, 11, 101, 1001}}'

I believe that this mimics the `NeigborhoodGraph` approach above, but is still much faster than using `NeighborhoodGraph`:

```
VertexList[Subgraph[gg, Union[VertexInComponent[gg, 1, 1], 
      VertexOutComponent[gg, 1, 1]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000306, {1, 2, 11, 101, 1001}}

The last two approaches are also faster than `NeighborhoodVertices` from the `GraphUtilities` package:

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
NeighborhoodVertices[gg, 1, 1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.017248, {1, 2, 11, 101, 1001}}

I'm working with large graphs that I need to manipulate quickly for several interactive information visualization tools. Any tips on why NeighborhoodGraph is so slow here and how to best use the new Graph package when speed is an issue?

Comment: I had this problem myself recently. I have no idea about an answer. I ended up using `NeighborhoodVertices`.  Just replaced it with `VertexComponents`.  Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that `NeighborhoodGraph` is attempting to infer the layout of the original `GridGraph`. The layout algorithm for the parent graph is responsible for the slowness. At the cost of loosing the layout information this can be sped-up:

```
In[1]:= gg = GridGraph[{10, 10, 10, 10}, GraphLayout -> None];

In[2]:= VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[gg, 1, 1]] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[2]= {0.0199998, {1, 2, 11, 101, 1001}}
```

The `GraphLayout -> None` has the effect that `Graph` object is not automatically rendered:

[image]

In version 9 and later, the simpler

```
NeighborhoodGraph[g, n, GraphLayout -> None]
```

form can be used for much faster neighbourhood graph computations.

Comment: Why does `NeighbourhoodGraph` need to invoke the layout algorithm?  Computing the layout is not necessary if the graph is never shown (like here) ...  Is this behaviour intentional or is this a bug?

Comment: @Szabolcs It is so that `NeighborhoodGraph` could be used with `HighlightGraph`, e.g. `gr = GridGraph[{3, 3, 3, 3}]; HighlightGraph[gr, NeighborhoodGraph[gr, 1, 1]]`.

Comment: In the meantime R.M. told me in the chatroom that `NeighborhoodGraph` preserves layout information (original vertex coordinates), which is useful sometimes.  This information isn't really necessary for `HighlightGraph` though, for example `HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, VertexList@NeighborhoodGraph[g, 1]]]` works even though `Subgraph` doesn't seem to preserve the original vertex coordinates.

Comment: Maybe in a future version `NeighborhoodGraph[g, 1, GraphLayout -> None]` could be made to not compute the layout of `g` to make it simpler to keep a good performance and still use `NeighborhoodGraph`?  I can't wait to see how `Graph` was improved in v9 :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs Your suggested behavior is already implemented in v9.

Comment: I think this behaviour is a serious usability issue.  It is just not easy to figure out why `NeighborhoodGraph` is so slow.  I saw this question when it was asked and I saw your answer, I even commented on it.  Yet I completely forgot about it and this afternoon I ended up reimplementing NeighborhoodGraph because I thought the built-in one was just too slow ... of course the `GraphLayout -> None` fix is easy, but it's just not easy to discover it, and it's also not easy to keep this strange behaviour in mind if one doesn't use the function too often ...

Comment: I'm sure many people are hit by this issue and they never realise what the solution is ... they probably just conclude that Mathematica is too slow for these kinds of computations which is of course not the case ...  I really wish that people in charge of developing the graph functionality would consider this.  Do you suggest I send a suggestion to support about this?

Comment: A question: do you know why `SetOptions[NeighborhoodGraph, GraphLayout -> None]` doesn't do what one would expect it to?  `NeighborhoodGraph` is still slow unless I pass the `GraphLayout -> None` with each call.

Answer (score 4):

In my [Boggle answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5392/5), I used a custom function to get the adjacent nodes for a vertex directly from the adjacency matrix . Not only is this much faster than using `NeighborhoodGraph`, it also gives you the adjacent nodes for *all the nodes* at once, so subsequent calls are instantaneous (you only need to index it). Here's the solution:

```
gg = GridGraph[{10, 10, 10, 10}];
adjNodes = With[{list = First /@ ArrayRules[AdjacencyMatrix@gg] // Most}, 
    Map[Last, SplitBy[list, First], {2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.138181, Null} *)
```

In comparison, `NeighborhoodGraph` takes around 3.38 seconds for *each vertex*! To get the adjacent nodes for a vertex $v$, simply take the $v$th part of `adjNodes` (these are instantaneous):

```
adjNodes[[2]]
(* {1, 3, 12, 102, 1002} *)

adjNodes[[8764]]
(* {7764, 8664, 8754, 8763, 8765, 8774, 8864, 9764} *)
```

You can verify that you get the same result as `Rest@VertexList@NeighborhoodGraph[gg, 8764, 1]`. This approach is very useful when you have a single large graph and you need to navigate it repeatedly.