# Solving a tridiagonal system of linear equations using the Thomas algorithm

Tags: programming, linear-algebra

I'm trying to write a function that can solve a tridiagonal system of linear equations using the Thomas algorithm. It basically solves the following equation. (Details can be found at the Wiki page here [Tridiagonal matrix algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm).)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   {b_ 1} & {c_ 1} & {   } & {   } & { 0 } \\
   {a_ 2} & {b_ 2} & {c_ 2} & {   } & {   } \\
   {   } & {a_ 3} & {b_ 3} & \ddots & {   } \\
   {   } & {   } & \ddots & \ddots & {c_{n-1}}\\
   { 0 } & {   } & {   } & {a_n} & {b_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
   {x_ 1 }  \\
   {x_ 2 }  \\
   {x_ 3 }  \\
   \vdots   \\
   {x_n }  \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
   {d_ 1 }  \\
   {d_ 2 }  \\
   {d_ 3 }  \\
   \vdots   \\
   {d_n }  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This can be done easily in various ways in *Mathematica* using the built-in functions such as `Solve`, `LinearSolve`, `LUDecomposition`, etc. Instead of using *Mathematica*'s wonderful black box solvers, I have decided to follow the procedures in the algorithm and write my own version which I can better control.

Here is the procedure in detail:

$$
c'_i=
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{lcl}
  \cfrac{c_i}{b_i}                  &&; i = 1 \\
  \cfrac{c_i}{b_i - c'_{i - 1} a_i} &&; i = 2, 3, \
\dots, n-1 \\
\end{array}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
d'_i=
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{lcl}
  \cfrac{d_i}{b_i}                  &&; i = 1 \\
  \cfrac{d_i - d'_{i - 1} a_i}{b_i - c'_{i - 1} a_i} &&; i = 2, 3, \dots, n. \\
\end{array}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
x_n&=&d'_n\\
x_i&=&d'_i-c'_ix_{i+1}
\end{array}
$$

I tried to write the function in *Mathematica* like this:

```
tridag[{a_, b_, c_}, d_] := 
 Module[{n = Length[d], c1 = Range[Length[d]], d1 = Range[Length[d]], x = Range[Length[d]]},
   c1[[1]] = c[[1]]/b[[1]];
   d1[[1]] = c1[[1]]/c[[1]]*d[[1]];
   Do[c1[[i]] = c[[i]]/(b[[i]] - a[[i]]*c1[[i - 1]]);
     d1[[i]] = c1[[i]]/c[[i]]*(d[[i]] - a[[i]] d1[[i - 1]]);, {i, 2, n - 1}];
   x[[n]] = d1[[n]];
   Do[x[[i]] = d1[[i]] - c1[[i]]*x[[i + 1]], {i, n - 1, 1, -1}];
 x]
```

where a, b, c are the three diagonal rows in the matrix.

For a test case of

```
A = {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 3, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 5}};
R = {5, 15, 31, 53, 45};
```

my function gives the same answer as *Mathematica*'s linear solver:

```
LinearSolve[A, R]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

```
tridag[{PadLeft[Diagonal[A, 1], 5], Diagonal[A], PadRight[Diagonal[A, -1], 5]}, R]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Here are my questions:

1. Since I am just a novice, my function is simply a direct translation of the above procedurual equations. So I would like to learn a really functional *Mathematica* way of implementing this function (other than using the built-in solver)?
2. A more general question is that, given an algorithm written in a procedure way, i.e., with implementation in a procedure language like C or Fortran in mind, how can it be translated into functional *Mathematica* code? Can you give some examples or suggestions or guidelines?

#### Edit

As belisarius points out, "'the real elegant Mathematica way' is always to use an already implemented function". To be clear, I'm not asking how to implement a solver that is superior to the built-in solver. I'm just asking how to implement a solver in the *Mathematica* way, i.e., in the functional way. I think knowing how to write one's own solver is helpful when using the built-in solvers. It gives the user confidence when the built-in solver does not work. An example may be the `HilbertMatrix`:

```
LinearSolve[ HilbertMatrix [10], Table[Random[], {10}]]
```

> LinearSolve::luc: "Result for LinearSolve of badly conditioned matrix
>   {{1., 0.5, 0.333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.166667, 0.142857, 0.125, 0.111111, 0.1}, <<8>>, 
>   {0. 1, 0.0909091, 0.0833333, 0. 0769231, 0.0714286, 0.0666667, 0.0625,0.0588235, 
>   0.0555556, 0.0526316}} may contain significant numerical errors."

Besides, I think trying to implement a simple solver is a good way for me as a new hand to learn the *Mathematica* language.

Comment: @belisarius maybe I should not use the word "elegant", I just want to learn how to implement such a solver by the usual Mathematica way, in the concept such as manipulation of a list as a whole object, recursion, etc.

Comment: Letting `m` be the matrix, `Last /@ RowReduce[Join[m, {d}\[Transpose], 2]]` *faithfully* implements this algorithm.  I suspect even @belisarius might not downvote this solution :-). If you insist the algorithm be expressed in terms of the vectors `a`, `b`, and `c`, then begin with `m = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> a, Band[{1, 1}] -> b, Band[{1, 2}] -> c}];`.

Comment: a carefully considered [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4877/52) can sometimes outstrip built ins, and sometimes you can get amazing speed out out of strictly [high-level code](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5394/52). So, @belisarius argument aside, _Mathematica_ uses LAPACK as a back-end solver, so it might be tough to beat with high-level code.

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment, but RowReduce is still a black box Gaussian elimination function, if my understanding is right.

Comment: @Nasser, yes, that's exactly what I need. I'm very interested to see how one can transform a Fortran style program to a compact functional style. It would be great if you can do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser I would be very surprised if Fortran would be slower than any Mathematica implemention ...

Comment: OK, then replace _elegant_ by _functional_ and I'll remove my downvoting menace :D

Comment: @belisarius thanks, I've replaced them :) .

Comment: @xslittlegrass I agree that `RowReduce` is "black box." The purpose in offering that solution is to demonstrate that there's nothing special about the Thomas algorithm; it's just a special case of row reduction. At the end, whatever algorithm you code has to rely on *some* primitive operations, whether they are addition or row reduction or something in between. At this point it seems we're guessing a little concerning just how far to go and when to stop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to go about building the answer in a "loop free" manner. First define the matrix and vector:

```
 mat = {{1, 2, 0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 3, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 3, 4, 0}, 
        {0, 0, 4, 4, 5}, {0, 0, 0, 5, 5}};;
 d = {5, 15, 31, 53, 45};
 {n, n} = Dimensions[mat];
```

Next extract out the a,b,c elements:

```
 b = Diagonal[mat];
 c = Flatten[{Diagonal[mat, 1], 0}];
 a = Flatten[{0, Diagonal[mat, -1]}];
```

Define three functions that we are going to iterate on, these are the same as the definitions of $c'$ and $d'$ and $x$ in your algorithm statement.

```
 cPrime[x_, {ax_, bx_, cx_}] := cx/(bx - x ax);
 dPrime[x_, {ax_, bx_, cpx_, dx_}] := (dx - x ax)/(bx - cpx ax);
 xOut[x_, {cpx_, dpx_}] := dpx - x cpx;
```

Now do the iterations using FoldList[ ]:

```
 cp = Rest[FoldList[cPrime, c[[1]]/b[[1]], Transpose[{a, b, c}]]];
 dp = Rest[FoldList[dPrime, d[[1]]/b[[1]], 
                  Transpose[{a, b, Flatten[{0, Drop[cp, -1]}], d}]]];
out = Reverse[FoldList[xOut, dp[[n]], 
                  Transpose[{Rest[Reverse[cp]], Rest[Reverse[dp]]}]]];
```

For the matrix you suggested, the output is {1,2,3,4,5} in agreement with your tridag[ ] module.

This can easily be made more concise using pure functions, which means that it is not necessary to define the cPrime, dPrime and xOut functions explicitly. In the pure notation form, the complete algorithm can be written:

```
 triThomas[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Module[{cp,dp}, 
    cp = Rest[FoldList[#2[[3]]/(#2[[2]] - #1 #2[[1]] ) &, c[[1]]/b[[1]], 
         Transpose[{a, b, c}]]];
    dp = Rest[FoldList[(#2[[4]] - #1 #2[[1]])/(#2[[2]] - #2[[3]] #2[[1]]) &, 
         d[[1]]/b[[1]], Transpose[{a, b, Flatten[{0, Drop[cp, -1]}], d}]]];
    Reverse[FoldList[(#2[[2]] - #1 #2[[1]]) &, dp[[n]], 
          Transpose[{Rest[Reverse[cp]], Rest[Reverse[dp]]}]]]]
```

Here, the symbol #1 refers to the first (implicit) argument and the symbols #2[[n]] refer to the nth element of the second argument.

This can be called by

```
 triThomas[a, b, c, d]
```

which gives the same answer as above.

Answer (score 5):

Prior to version 5 users had to [load an add on package](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/AddOns/StandardPackages/LinearAlgebra/Tridiagonal.html) that contained a tridiagonal solver based on the Thomas algorithm

I think the code for those old packages is probably accessible somewhere. I found this in the library archive:

http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4827/

This package uses Compile. The earlier built in add-on package was actually quite slow from memory because it was procedural but not compiled. Users had the code though so could make their own compiled versions. Back in the day I had a functional version which was close to what @bill s has posted but reverted to the compiled procedural version for performance.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. It seems in this package the tridiagonal solver is just a copy of the solver in the Numerical Recipe. I guess my main worry was that using mathematica as the way of fortran or c(a lot of "do", "for", "if" etc.) will harm the performance, but I guess that is not true, right?

Comment: @xslittlegrass If you use "straight out" procedural code in Mma it will be very slow relative to functional code. Using `Compile` *can* alleviate this relative slowness. If you are new to Mma probably best to learn functional ways ...like bill s answer.