# How can I speed up my code?

Tags: linear-algebra, parallelization, performance-tuning

```
For[n = 2500, n < 10000, n += 500, 
  sum = 0;
  pp = N[1/HarmonicNumber[n, 2]];
  A = Reverse[IdentityMatrix[n]];
  H = IdentityMatrix[n];
  For[i = 0, i < n, i++, 
    For[j = 1, j < n + 1 - i, j++, 
      H[[j, j + i]] = Sqrt[pp]/(N[Sqrt[n - i]*(i + 1)])]];
  T := A.Orthogonalize[N[H].A, Dot];
  Z = T.N[H].A.T\[Transpose].A;
  sum = Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[Z,1]])^2];
  Print[sum]
]
```

I have run this program for a long time to get the result for `n = 2500` (about 12 hours) and no more result till now (more than 3 days). I want to know how to make it more efficient. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: An obvious suggestion: produce a short version of your routine that takes just 30 seconds. Next, work out where most time is spent. Optimize that piece. Run it for a bit longer, see what's changed. Then, Rinse and repeat.

Comment: for example `Sum[1/i^2, {i, 1, n}] == HarmonicNumber[n, 2]` and is always better to work with built in functions. I have also bad experience with `For` I would use `Do` if there is no way to implement `Nest`, `Map` etc.

Comment: Thank you all! Does N[Sqrt[..]] will help? And how to learn about the built in functions?

Comment: @user8934 sometimes it helps to keep symbolic expression, if it is going to reduce something but usualy for "real" data it is going to slow down calculations. You can learn by analyzing your code and testing what can be replaced by checking this in documentation center. Also there are a lot of useful Q&A here. [avoiding procedural loops](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/5478)

Comment: I think `A = Reverse[IdentityMatrix[n]]` should provide the same result as your two lines initializing `A`, but it should a little faster/cleaner.

Comment: Year, thanks a lot! I just do not know this function.

Comment: You can use `UpperTriangularize[Z,1]` to zero everything on the main and lower diagonals. And sum it like: `Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[Z,1]])^2]`

Comment: Thanks so much! It's very helpful!

Comment: @Kuba there are exceptions ([1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5394/52), [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5394/52)) to that rule. But, you are correct, in general built-in is faster, just not always.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a lot going on with your code, as already pointed out by others. But, I would like to point out a few more things, and this was *much*, *much* to long for a comment.

First, I would use `SparseArray` to generate `H`, instead of the pre-allocate, fill-in method you are using, as follows:

```
H = SparseArray[
 {l_, m_} /; m >= l :> Sqrt[pp]/(Sqrt[n + l - m] (m - l + 1)),
 {n, n}
];
```

**Edit**: looking at the timing for this, and as pointed out in the comments by ssch, the calculation of `H` can be sped up significantly by using `Array`, instead:

```
diags = Sqrt[1./HarmonicNumber[n, 2]]/(Sqrt[n - #] (# + 1)& @ 
     Range[0., n - 1]); 
H = Array[If[#2 < #1, 0., diags[[#2 - #1 + 1]]] &, {n, n}];
```

For large matrices, this scales significantly better for large `n`. For instance, at `n = 500` the `SparseArray` method takes 3.3 secs v. 0.028 secs for the `Array` method.

**End Edit**

This generates an upper-triangular matrix, with `m - l` taking the place of `i` in your loops. Also, I got rid of the extra `N` as it is not necessary because `pp` is already a machine number from your use of `N` in its definition. Similarly, all `N[H]` can be replaced with `H`, further down in the code. While it may not provide much of a speed up, do not overuse a function if you don't have to.

Second, in terms of overuse, the way you have defined `T` means it will be regenerated every time it is used. `Orthogonalize` is not a fast operation, so don't make more work for yourself. I would define `T` as

```
T = A.Orthogonalize[H.A];
```

where I am using `Set` (`=`), instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`), and I have removed the second argument to `Orthogonalize`. By default, `Orthogonalize` effectively uses `Dot`, but by specifying the argument, you may be forgoing potential speed ups. If this is true in this case, I do not know, I have not tested it. But, it holds true in a lot of other cases, so be cautious about overriding defaults.

Third, `A.M.A == M`. This simplifies the definition of `Z` to

```
Z = T.H.Transpose[T]
```

**Edit**: That is not true, in general. But, $A^T = A$ and $AA = I$, so

$$A(ABA)^TA = AAB^TAA = B^T,$$

and combined with

```
Othogonalize[H.A] == Orthogonalize[H].A
```

as discussed by [Daniel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30108/52), both `T` and `Z` can be rewritten:

```
T = Orthogonalize[H];
Z = A.T.A.H.Transpose[T];
```

But, as `A` is just a permutation, it can be best effected by using `Part`, and using Daniel's notation:

```
negrange = -Range[n];
Z = T[[negrange, negrange]].H.Transpose[T];
```

Fourth, timing shows that the longest running part of the code is `Orthogonalize`. On my machine, at `n = 2500` this step along can take over a minute. An alternative is to use [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) which generates an upper triangular matrix, $R$, and an orthogonal matrix, $Q$, that forms a basis for the column space of the matrix being decomposed. So, to get an orthogonal basis out of the row space, you take the transpose. The definition of `T` becomes

```
T = QRDecomposition[Transpose[H]][[1]];
```

The function below has been edited with these changes.

**End Edit**

Lastly, I would put the entire contents of the outer `For` into a separate function, sans the `Print` statement. `Print` does not provide results in a form usable for further processing, but as you were using `For`, its use is understandable. Additionally, putting it into a separate function allows you to use any number of methods for generating your data. With the changes I have suggested above, this looks like

```
myFunction[n_Integer?Positive] :=
Block[{negrange, diags, H, T, Z},
  diags = Sqrt[1./HarmonicNumber[n, 2]]/(Sqrt[n - #] (# + 1)& @ 
     Range[0., n - 1]); 
  H = Array[If[#2 < #1, 0., diags[[#2 - #1 + 1]]] &, {n, n}]; 
  T = QRDecomposition[Transpose[H]][[1]];
  negrange = -Range[n];
  Z = T[[negrange, negrange]].H.Transpose[T];
  Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[Z,1]])^2]
]
```

**Edit**: Timings on my computer:

```
n     Timing (s)
2500  15.05
3000  24.31
3500  37.61
4000  54.56
```

So, while not fast, it scales significantly better than the previous versions.

**End Edit**

As this is likely to be a long running process, I would run it as follows:

```
Internal`WithLocalSettings[
  strm = OpenWrite["output.log"];
  AppendTo[ $Output, strm ],

  Scan[Print[#, "\t", myFunction[#]]&, Range[2500, 10000, 500]],

  $Output = Drop[$Output, -1];
  Close[strm]
]
```

where a `Print` will output to both a log-file and the screen. This allows you to save the output as you go.  If you don't need this, then just use `Table`.

**Edit - Last words**:

The key here is simply to ***profile*** your code. Examine each step and find out which is slow. As shown above, while I like the simplicity of using `SparseArray`, it scales badly compared to using `Array`, so for efficiency sake `SparseArray` is out. The same thing goes for `Orthogonalize` v. `QRDecomposition`. As you might not be familiar with the properties of `QRDecomposition`, that is when you ask: `Orthogonalize` scales badly, are there alternatives?

The other advice is to reduce redundancy. Only do something once, if you can get away with it. There are times where you won't be able to, like you run out of memory, but if you can, it often will save time.

Comment: `H` can be sped up significantly by first calculating the diagonals and then using `Array` to construct the matrix by picking appropriate diagonal (or 0) `diags = Sqrt[1./HarmonicNumber[n, 2]]/(Sqrt[n - #] (# + 1)&@Range[0., n - 1]);
H = Array[If[#2 < #1, 0., diags[[#2 - #1 + 1]]] &, {n, n}];`

Comment: @ssch interesting timing results. At n = 500, H takes 3.3 v. 0.027 and T takes 0.37 v. 0.25. `Array` is the clear winner. (I was looking at that, but separating out the diagonals eluded me.) I did not try the `SparseArray` version n = 2000, as I don't like locking up my computer, but the `Array` version comes in at 0.36 for H, 7.15 for T, and 3.58 for Z (up from 0.13 at n = 500). At n = 2500, T balloons out to 53.5 and Z takes 7.31. Clearly, not scaling well.

Comment: Interesting. `A` can be replaced with `Reverse`, that is: `T =Reverse[Orthogonalize[(Reverse /@ H)]];` And Householder orthogonalization seems way faster: `T = Reverse[Orthogonalize[(Reverse /@ H), Method -> "Householder"]];`

Comment: @ssch the speed up on my machine comes from replacing `A` with `Reverse`, but `Method -> "Householder"` takes over a second longer.

Comment: Thanks everyone! A.M.A is not same as M, for example, M={{a,b},{c,d}}, then A.M.A={{d,c},{b,a}}

Comment: @user8934 you are correct. I addressed that above in my edit, alongside a massive speed-up for `Orthogonalize`.

Comment: Is that really sped up from OP's 12 hours to 15 seconds?! That's what I call a good answer!

Comment: @cormullion the trick is not use `Orthogonalize` which scales very badly. I don't know how fast it will run on the OPs computer, but it should be significant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it only output'n myFunction[n]' in screen and 'n"\t"myFunction[n]' in the output.log when I   adopt the second suggestion.

Comment: @user8934 that's because I'm an idiot. Fixed the code.

Comment: whatif this version?  hh = ({
    {a, b, c, d, e, f, g},
    {0, h, i, j, k, l, f},
    {0, 0, m, n, o, k, e},
    {0, 0, 0, p, n, j, d},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, m, i, c},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, h, b},
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a}
   });
orth = Orthogonalize[hh];
negrange = Range[Length[orth], 1, -1];
z3 = orth[[negrange, negrange]].hh.Transpose[orth];
sum = Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[z3, 1]])^2];
FindMaximum[{sum, 
  2*a^2 + 2*b^2 + 2*c^2 + 2*d^2 + 2*e^2 + 2*f^2 + g^2 + 2*h^2 + 
    2*i^2 + 2*j^2 + 2*k^2 + l^2 + 2*m^2 + 2*n^2 + o^2 + p^2 == 1}, {a,
   b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p}]

Comment: @user8934 First, `QRDecomposition` requires a numeric matrix, so you'd have to use `Orthogonalize`. Second, you lose a lot of the other speed ups, too. So, I wouldn't except with very small matrices.

Comment: The above one takes 14844.055031s.

Comment: @user8934 First question: where is it slow?

Comment: Too many variables. For a four dimesion version it only take a few seconds! Reseting accuracy may be helpful? How to do it?

Comment: @EdenHarder is it slow in `Orthogonalize` of `FindMaximum`? And, accuracy is irrelevant in symbolic calcs.

Comment: @rcollyer Orthogonalize will not take a minute, it is FindMaximum that take a lot of time.

Comment: @EdenHarder I don't know. Sounds like another question to me.

Comment: Yeah, it is another question. Thank you and other answers very much!

Comment: @EdenHarder don't forget to mark the best answer as accepted, as per the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @EdenHarder thanks for the accept. Would you mind posting a few timings of the code on your machine?

Comment: For the numerical(original) version, 'n' and 'timing(s)' are '2500, 7.160000', '3000, 11.272000', '3500, 16.968000', '4000, 24.328000'.

Comment: For the symbolic version, 'n' and 'timing(s)' for Orthogonize and FindMaximum are '4, 0.048000, 0.296000', '5, 0.500000, 9.200000' '6, 10.824000, 338.924000', '7, unknown, 14844.055031'.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure one can get the larger cases due to memory needs. The code below, which uses the array generation of @rcollyer, seems reasonably effective at least for the smaller end.

```
n = 2500;
Timing[sum = 0;
 diags = Sqrt[
    1./HarmonicNumber[n, 2]]/(Sqrt[n - #] (# + 1) &@Range[0., n - 1]);
  hh = Array[If[#2 < #1, 0., diags[[#2 - #1 + 1]]] &, {n, n}]; 
 orth = Orthogonalize[hh];
 negrange = Range[Length[orth], 1, -1]; 
 z3 = orth[[negrange, negrange]].hh.Transpose[orth]; 
 sum = Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[z3, 1]])^2]]

(* {16.630000, 0.415096142869} *)
```

--- edit ---

This shows more timings at the lower end of the desired range.

```
Do[
 time = Timing[sum = 0;
   diags = 
    Sqrt[1./HarmonicNumber[n, 2]]/(Sqrt[n - #] (# + 1) &@
       Range[0., n - 1]); 
   hh = Array[If[#2 < #1, 0., diags[[#2 - #1 + 1]]] &, {n, n}]; 
   orth = Orthogonalize[hh];
   negrange = Range[Length[orth], 1, -1]; 
   z3 = orth[[negrange, negrange]].hh.Transpose[orth];
   sum = Total[(Flatten[UpperTriangularize[z3, 1]])^2]
   ];
 Print[{n, time, sum}];
 {time, sum},
 {n, 2500, 5000, 500}]

{2500,{17.230000,0.415096142869},0.415096142869}

{3000,{29.170000,0.415356679612},0.415356679612}

{3500,{45.930000,0.41554482016},0.41554482016}

{4000,{68.400000,0.415687180722},0.415687180722}

{4500,{96.070000,0.415798728445},0.415798728445}

{5000,{130.300000,0.415888533453},0.415888533453}
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: `Orthogonalize[H.A]` per the OP gives a different result than `Orthogonalize[H]` which may or may not be okay, depending on the purpose of `Orthogonalize` here.

Comment: @rcollyer `Orthogonalize[H.A] == Orthogonalize[H] . A` because A just rearranges rows or columns, depending on which side you multiply from. This also is how i got rid of some dot products (I removed others from the fact that `A.A` is the identity matrix). I actually tested/validated my results against the code from the OP.

Comment: @rcollyer Let me slightly correct myself. Multiplying by `A` on the right rearranges columns. This is an important distinction because a row rearrangement would not commute with orthogonalization.

Comment: On `Orthogonalize[H.A] == Orthogonalize[H].A`, you seem to be correct. I get a fairly low Frobenius norm on their differences, $\sim 10^{-14}$. But, I get a substantial norm with `A.Orthogonalize[H].A - Orthogonalize[H]`, $\sim 68.8$. I don't have a ready explanation as to why, but it explains the differences I get between the calculated values our codes generate. I get $0.391274$, but changing your code to use `A.Orthogonalize[H].A`, I get $0.246054$.

Comment: @rcollyer Note though that I did not use `Orthogonalize[H]` in lieu of `A.Orthogonalize[H].A`. I instead used a row and column reversed form of `Orthogonalize[H]`. It is the same as `A.Orthogonalize[H].A`.

Comment: Really? Your construction of `hh` looks identical to my construction of `H`. Where do the reversals come in? Never mind, I see it, at least in part ...

Comment: I edited my comment above to reflect the fact that I noticed it after I commented.

Comment: I think you're missing a term, then. `Transpose[orth]` should be `Transpose[orth[[negrange, negrange]]]`. Then it gives the same results I get.

Comment: @rcollyer No, in my code that second one loses the surrounding `A` factors because `Transpose[A]==A` and `A.A` is the identity.

Comment: You're correct. I hadn't fully worked through the math. Next time, I'll try not to be as hasty. :)

Comment: @rcollyer I notice you put QRDecomposition to good use. I had been meaning to try that but never quite got around to it. Very nice (and an upvote).