# Solving CROSS TIES automatically

Tags: dictionary

A clever puzzle in the *Sunday New York Times Magazine* is CROSS TIES (by Will Shortz).  You are given a $5 \times 5$ grid with some squares filled with letters, others grayed out, and yet others white.  The puzzle is to fill in the remaining white squares with letters so as to spell valid English words or names that all are examples *from the same category* or *class*.

One puzzle is shown on the left, and its solution (with red letters) is at the right:

[image: CROSS TIES PUZZLE AND SOLUTION]

It is a fairly straightforward *Mathematica* search to find all dictionary words that fit the constraints of a given word, for example:

```
DictionaryLookup["w"~~_~~"is"~~_]
```

and

```
DictionaryLookup[_~~"o"~~_]
```

for two of them here.

I'm seeking an elegant method to impose all the constraints (by defining variable-letter names) so that the routine returns only the final solution words.  (You can hand-code the problem-specific data for each such puzzle.)

The ideal case would be to also demand all solution words be *semantically related*... to enforce the semantic constraint of the problem.  (Frankly, I suspect that most puzzles are so constrained that only the intended solution words will fit, but in some cases others might fit as well.)

Test your solution out on this:

[image: CROSS TIES PROBLEM]

Another:

[image]

Another:

[image]

---

Here's a first pass at a solution, admittedly a bit ugly and efficient, and not in a *Mathematica* style.

Consider a simple but relevant example:

[image: sample problem]

Then something like:

```
solutions = {};
words = {DictionaryLookup["w" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _],
   DictionaryLookup[_ ~~ _ ~~ "o"],
   DictionaryLookup[_ ~~ _ ~~ "g"]};

Table[
  If[(StringTake[words[[1, i]], {2}] == 
     StringTake[words[[2, j]], {2}]) && 
    (StringTake[words[[1, i]], {4}] == 
     StringTake[words[[3, k]], {1}]), 
   AppendTo[solutions, {words[[1, i]], words[[2, j]], words[[3, k]]}]],
  {i, Length[words[[1]]]},
  {j, Length[words[[2]]]},
  {k, Length[words[[3]]]}
  ];

solutions
```

Surely there is a more elegant way to perform this...

Comment: Can you share the code which you used to generate the example/test case?

Comment: @CATrevillian:  My code did not generate the *problems*... I just copied the problems in today's magazine.

Comment: Ah, my mistake! The last one you include appeared different than the previous, leading to my inquiry. Thank you for this fun puzzle (to solve a puzzle!). Are they only in the magazine? I can’t seem to find a decent resource to see them online.

Comment: Note that solutions aren't guaranteed to be unique, e.g.
$$\text{WAIST}\\
\text{■D■■O}\\
\text{■UNTO}\\
\text{■L■■■}\\
\text{ITCH■}$$

Comment: J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties...  This is a (partial) solution... That's why the full problem constrained the words to be *about the same general topic*.  A sophisticated code would (somehow) include semantic cohesion.  But did you solve that by hand?

Comment: I think word vectors are the solution here. You want to constrain your results to words that are only a certain distance from one another. There are a lot of word vectors generated by neural networks [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/tasktype/Feature-Extraction/) or there is a built in `"WordVectors"` classifier.

Comment: Excellent idea.  How to implement it?

Comment: There's probably a lot to learn from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/how-can-i-use-mathematicas-graph-functions-to-cheat-at-boggle/5392.  I'm supposed to be *working* from home right now, but will pick this up again later.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork are the words supposed to be nouns only?

Comment: No...  I don't think they need be nouns only.  I *do* suspect, though, that within one puzzle they should all be nouns, or all verbs, or all adjectives, or all names...

Comment: For those who want to try further: 2nd: {{"mango"}, {"apple"}, {"pear"}, {"grape"}} 3rd: {{"harp"}, {"piano"}, {"organ"}, {"oboe"}}