# Building a tree

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, trees

Given a list of word characters, such as this one, I'd like to build a tree, similar to [this makeTree function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5394/109), but with the tree in a different format. So, for an input such as

```
test = {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"h", "o", "l", "o"}, {"h", 
    "e", "a"}, {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "s"}, {"b", "r", "o"}};
```

I'd like the output to be

```
output = StartOfString[
  "h"["e"["a"[EndOfString], 
    "l"["l"["o"[EndOfString, "s"[EndOfString]]]]], 
   "o"["l"["o"[EndOfString]]]], "b"["r"["o"[EndOfString]]]]
```

So that

```
TreeForm@output
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So far I haven't got a perfect solution, that's why I'm not posting. I know I must be missing lots of good ways to do this. What I want is not so much one single good solution, or "a fix to what I tried", but to see several ways to tackle the problem, particularly but not at all limited to elegant rule-based solutions

Comment: You know I don't post homework or without trying so if you want to close it I'll stay here defending it. It better be 5 against 1

Comment: brb, while I close this question with the force of a thousand suns! :P

Comment: I think you're missing an `"l"` in "hollow" within the `output` and `TreeForm`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard let's say I had an extra "l" in the input so I don't have to reupload the image :)

Comment: @Rojo, take a look at the timing study w/ recursive version - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69942/10-0-2-breaks-a-recursive-trie-query/69946#69946

Comment: @alancalvitti thanks, and happy new year

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I favor tree transformations, so I would reuse the `makeTree` function you linked to (because it is reasonably efficient), as follows:

```
ClearAll[makeRojoTree];
makeRojoTree[words_List] :=
 StartOfString @@ 
  ReplaceRepeated[
    makeTree[words], {
       ({} -> {}) :> EndOfString, 
        Rule[x_, l_List] :> x @@ l
    }
  ]
```

The argument can be either a list of words, or a list of lists of words characters (as in your test), since `makeTree` is already polymorphic. Applying it to your test, we get:

```
makeRojoTree[test]

(*

StartOfString[
  "h"["e"["l"["l"["o"[EndOfString, "s"[EndOfString]]]], 
  "a"[EndOfString]], "o"["l"["l"["o"[EndOfString]]]]], 
  "b"["r"["o"[EndOfString]]]
]

*)
```

which is slightly different in terms of ordering of the branches from what you have as a desired answer, but this can be fixed if you impose some specific ordering.

Comparing the performance to `makeTree` itself, we see that it is only about 1.5 times slower:

```
allWords=DictionaryLookup["*"];

(allTree=makeTree[allWords]);//Timing

(* {5.297,Null} *)

(rTree = makeRojoTree[allWords]);//AbsoluteTiming

(* {8.4375000,Null} *)
```

**EDIT**

To make this self contained, this is a slightly tuned up version of the linked `makeTree`, with the slightly different behaviour that it keeps duplicates

```
ClearAll[makeTree];
makeTree[wrds : {__String}] := makeTree[Characters[wrds]];
makeTree[{b___, {}, a___}] := Prepend[makeTree[{b, a}], {} -> {}];
makeTree[wrds_] := 
 Reap[Scan[Sow[Rest[#], First@#] &, 
    wrds], _, #1 -> makeTree[#2] &][[2]]
```

and this is a tweaked version of that that returns what the OP wants without resorting to the original `makeTree`

```
ClearAll[makeTreeRojo];
Module[{makeTreeRojoAux},
 makeTreeRojo[wrds_] := DeleteCases[StartOfString @@ makeTreeRojoAux[wrds], List, Infinity, Heads->True];
 makeTreeRojoAux[{b___, {}, a___}] := 
  Prepend[makeTreeRojoAux[{b, a}], EndOfString];
 makeTreeRojoAux[wrds_] := 
  Reap[Scan[Sow[Rest[#], First@#] &, 
     wrds], _, #1 @ makeTreeRojoAux[#2] &][[2]];
 ]
```

Comment: Nice one, +1... 1.5 times slower but less than half the storage, which isn't so much in either case

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. One could as well modify the original `makeTree` to squeeze some speed out, but I did not bother.

Comment: I'll see if I understand it now, squeeze some speed out, and offer to edit your answer, adding the code to make it self contained

Comment: @Rojo Be my guest. I am off to bed in 5 minutes, but feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Is there a way to remove the `EndOfString` from `makeTreeRojo`? I've been trying with no success whatsoever.

Comment: @Pragabhava Sorry, can't switch contexts to recall what was heppening here, right now. But why would you want to do that? It just serves to mark that there is an exact word with the contents matching the prefix tree path.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I've been trying to use your code to see the structure of a set of urls in `TreeFrom` view. There are a lot of entries and `EndOfString` is not only out of context, but it clogs up the tree a lot. By changing it for `Nothing`, I removed the clogging problem, but I ended up with a parenthesis in the last leafs of the tree. I was hoping there was a simple way to do this in your code, because I didn't want to hijack the answer (which now I'm doing :/ ).

Comment: @Pragabhava I suggest you ask this as a separate question with all the information and a minimal reproducible code example. Then you will have a much better chance to get an answer from somebody. You can link to this question and the code, in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a very concise way to convert the list of strings to your desired format:

```
StartOfString @@ (
    (Composition @@ #)[EndOfString] & /@ test //. h_[a___, x_[y__], b___, x_[z__], c___] :> h[x[y, z], a, b, c]

(* {"h"["e"["l"["l"["o"[EndOfString, "s"[EndOfString]]]], 
    "a"[EndOfString]], "o"["l"["l"["o"[EndOfString]]]]], "b"["r"["o"[EndOfString]]]} *)
```

This is a rather perverse use of [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html), but the fact that `Composition[f, g][x]` is `f[g[x]]` lends itself very nicely to the way in which you want your tree built.

Comment: Almost great! but check the `TreeForm`. The `e` in hello, hea, and hellos aren't groups

Comment: Btw, loved the Composition to "unflatten"

Comment: Thanks for helping fix my pattern! :)

Comment: Well deserved +1. Exactly the kind of answer I was (and still am) hoping to see appear

Comment: This is very nice conceptually, but a performance disaster for large lists of words / word letters (which is a general feature of this sort of patterns, alas). Since I think that performance is generally important for this type of problems, I don't upvote this time.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin No worries. The performance disaster was rather guaranteed with the use of `//.` and multiple `___` :) Nevertheless, I love this for some reason, because I would've never thought I'd use `Composition` this way...

Comment: I would vote for this for its beauty, if I did not know all too well that performance is important in the types of problems where this sort of constructs (trees) are likely to be used. Most of the time, one should not consider performance as the main and only criteria, but in cases like this it is likely to be important.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, can you take a look at the timing study here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69942/10-0-2-breaks-a-recursive-trie-query/69946#69946

Answer (score 2):

Using a recursive Query:

```
byPrefixTree = Query[{
     Query[Select[# != {} &] /* GroupBy[First], All, Rest], 
     Query[Select[# == {} &]]}] /* Merge[Join] /* 
   Query[All, First, byPrefixTree[#] &];
```

Can be used directly to reconstruct a directory tree from `FileNames[...,Infinity]`.

- Can it be optimized?  ~1000 files nested up to 15 folders deep took ~15sec.
- So far haven't been successful merging the 2 `Select` calls with a single `GroupBy[#=={}&]` as then the keys may be any subset of `{True,False}`. Wanted to `/*` with `MapAt` or similar
- Operator form is broken- throws a recursion limit exception.

On Rojo's data:

```
  testData = 
     test // AssociationMap[{SoS, Sequence @@ # , EoS} &] // 
       KeyMap[StringJoin] // Dataset
```

[image]

```
testData [byPrefixTree] // Normal

(* <|SoS-><|h-><|e-><|l-><|l-><|o-><|s-><|EoS-><|hellos-><||>|>|>,EoS-><|hello-><||>|>|>|>|>,a-><|EoS-><|hea-><||>|>|>|>,o-><|l-><|o-><|EoS-><|holo-><||>|>|>|>|>|>,b-><|r-><|o-><|EoS-><|bro-><||>|>|>|>|>|>|> *)
```

Desired form (though unsorted)

```
(testData[byPrefixTree][Map[Normal, #, All] &][First] // 
    Normal) //. {Rule[EoS, val_] :> EoS, 
   Rule[x_, l_] :> x @@ l} // TreeForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I may be off the mark by not making nested compositions. So, for what it's worth:

```
pref[list_] := (f[m_] := m[[1 ;; #]] & /@ Range[Length@m]; 
  g[t_] := Rule @@@ Partition[t, 2, 1]; 
  Module[{str = {StartOfString, ##, EndOfString} & @@@ (Characters /@ 
        list)}, TreePlot[Union[Flatten[g /@ (f /@ str)]], 
    Automatic, {StartOfString}, 
    VertexRenderingFunction -> ({LightYellow, EdgeForm[Black], 
        Rectangle[# - {0.4, 0.2}, # + {0.4, 0.2}], Black, 
        Text[Last@#2, #1]} &)]])
```

Testing:

```
pref[{"hello", "holo", "hea", "hellos", "bro"}]
```

[image]

```
pref[{"bro", "hea", "holo", "hello", "help"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For the lastest version on cloud:

```
Clear[ds];
test = {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"h", "o", "l", "o"}, {"h", "e", 
    "a"}, {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "s"}, {"b", "r", "o"}};
ds = CreateDataStructure["ByteTrie", "a", "z"];
str=StringJoin/@test;
ds["Insert", #] & /@ str; 

ds["Visualization"]
```

(* same output as shown below *)

---

**Original (ironically it works on v12.2)**

**Using `ByteTrie` data structure:** [Trie Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

```
Clear[ds]
test = {{"h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, {"h", "o", "l", "o"}, {"h", "e", 
    "a"}, {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "s"}, {"b", "r", "o"}};

ds = CreateDataStructure["ByteTrie", "a", "z"]
ds["Insert", #] & /@ test; (* It can take in string inputs as well *)

ds["Visualization"]
```

---

[image]

---

Methods such as "Strings" (stored) and "MemberQ" are available with the data structure.

```
{ds["MemberQ", "hello"], ds["FreeQ", "hello"]}
```

> {True, False}

Comment: Syed -    I get the following:    "DataStructure::err: ByteTrie encountered an error of type ExpressionConversion processing Insert."       ( Doc says that DataStructure is Experimental, in case it matters. )

Comment: I encounter the same error, Version 13.3 for Windows 11.

Comment: It seems that ByteTrie accepts strings and lists of character codes, but not lists of characters. Try Scan[ds["Insert", #]&, StringJoin/@test] or Scan[ds["Insert", #] &, ToCharacterCode[{"help", "hire"}]].

Comment: Regrettably, I have updated the answer to accommodate the regression.