# Implementing a dictionary data structure

Tags: data-structures

As one learns from a course on data structures, hash maps or dictionaries can be efficient when applied to appropriate tasks.

I need a hash map in *Mathematica* and I've never found it. I'm scratching in one of my notebooks files, and I find myself still using the following code ([Leonid Shifrin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IOpg3SGB6w0/Ha0TpoSJuEEJ)) to simulate this data structure.

```
ClearAll[linkedList, toLinkedList, fromLinkedList, addToList, pop, emptyList];
SetAttributes[linkedList, HoldAllComplete];
toLinkedList[data_List] := 
  Fold[linkedList, linkedList[], data];
fromLinkedList[ll_linkedList] := 
   List @@ Flatten[ll, Infinity, linkedList];

addToList[ll_, value_] := linkedList[ll, value];
pop[ll_] := Last@ll;
emptyList[] := linkedList[];

ClearAll[makeHash];
makeHash[] := Module[{hash}, 
   hash[_] := emptyList[];
   hash /: add[hash, key_, value_] := ash[key] = addToList[hash[key], value];
   hash /: get[hash, key_] := fromLinkedList@hash[key];
   Return[hash]];
```

I was wondering if any of you had needed a dictionary. If you have, I would like know how you implemented it. I'm interested to use a `map<string, int>`.

Comment: Could you give us a formal or semiformal description of the semantics you require for you dictionary data structure?

Comment: There's also a [prefix tree](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/447/52) ([trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)) which was used to great effect in [Boggle](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5394/52).

Comment: You got it from Leonid Shifrin's answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/IOpg3SGB6w0/Ha0TpoSJuEEJ). I found it by searching for his name because it uses the same naming convention as his code [over here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/731).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update:** Mathematica version 10 introduced the builtin [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) data structure (see [tutorial](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/associations/) and [answer below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38306/12)), which has most important features of dictionaries.

---

*Mathematica* has no *obvious* hash-table structure but what most people forget is, that the `DownValues` of symbols, which means the simple, always-used function definitions, are implemented using hashing. Therefore, the most straightforward way to create a dictionary from string to integer is by making definitions:

```
dict["hello"] = 1;
dict["blub"] = 2;
```

By setting a definition for `dict[___]` you can create a default rule, when the key is not in the dictionary.

Another thing you should look into is `Dispatch`, which

> generates an optimized dispatch table representation of a list of rules.

There hashing is used too and you can build your dictionary on a list of rules like

```
{"hello" -> 1, "blub" -> 2, ... }
```

Indeed, the documentation suggests, that's exactly this what is used to speed up function definitions:

> Lists of rules produced by assignments made with = and := are automatically optimized with dispatch tables when appropriate.

As pointed out by Faysal in his comment, please review the following Q&A:

[Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/187)

Comment: Ideas around such a dictionary structure here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/66

Comment: @FaysalAberkane Thanks, I was looking for exactly this because I was sure I have seen it around here but was unable to find it. I have included the reference in my answer.

Comment: Note that Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html), which has most of the important properties of a dictionary data structure.  It makes this answer (currently with the most votes) somewhat deprecated.

Comment: @JessRiedel  Rather than editing these older answers, consider submitting your own answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: In general I agree, but I'd argue that this is a special situation. Several answers have been made unambiguously defunct by an official Mathematica release designed explicitly to provide this functionality, and it can only confuse people to have the now-best answer buried.  Given the traffic on these articles, it could literally take years before the correct answer floats to the top.  A short edit reflecting the change of affairs ought to be justified.

Comment: The `Association` answer is the second best answer here and we can expect a user to read 3 answers, because what you forget is that `Association`'s only work in the latest version of *Mathematica*. There are very many users out there that don't have this version. Additionally, regarding the advertisement of `Association` it is more likely someone stumbles over this before realizing that a dictionary can easily be created using `DownValues`. And to end this discussion: The community decides. Always. If you like to point a greater audience on this issue, write a post on Meta.

Answer (score 15):

Mathematica 10 has introduced [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Association.html), which has most of the important properties of a dictionary data structure.

```
someData = <| "name" -> "Bob", "age" -> 23 |>

In[1]:= someData["name"]
Out[1]= Bob

In[2]:= someData["age"]
Out[2]= 23

In[3]:= someData[[2]]
Out[3]= 23
```

For more info, see

- [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html),
- [`DataSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) (which builds on `Association`)
- Wolfram guides: [Elementary introduction to DataSets](http://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/45-datasets.html) and [Fast introduction for programmers](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/associations/)
- Mathmatica.SE questions: [How to make use of Associations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations) and [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/993#993)
- [This HackerNews comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8012838).

Answer (score 8):

Salvatore Mangano implements a dictionary data structure in his [Mathematica Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521004.do) (ISBN: 978-0-596-52099-1, Copyright 2010 O'Reilly Media, Inc.). According to the copyright, I can share it with you ("answering a question by citing this book and quoting example code," as I am). For the same reasons as Halirutan mentions, more or less, he uses `DownValues` and relies on it, but as he says, you need more functionality to be able to work with the dictionary data structure efficiently. His functions are surely only meant to be a start, many other languages implement many more such functions. But his is a start to see how it can be done and to build on. I put them into a package. The usage messages are mine, but the code has only been touched to fix what I assume were type setting errors in the book:

```
BeginPackage["DataDictionary`"]

makeDictionary::usage =
        "makeDictionary[] initializes a new dictionary and returns an identifier.";
destroyDictionary::usage =
        "destroyDictionary[dictionary] destroys a dictionary.";
dictName::usage = 
        "dictName[dictionary] returns the internal symbol used for storing data in a dictionary.";
dictStore::usage = 
        "dictStore[dictionary, key, value] stores a value in a dictionary using a key.";
dictReplace::usage =
        "dictReplace[dictionary, key, value] works the same way as dictStore except that any duplicates in a dictionary will be removed.";
dictRemove::usage =
        "dictRemove[dictionary, key, value] removes a value that is stored in a  dictionary under a key.";
dictLookup::usage = 
        "dictLookup[dictionary, key] returns all values in a dictionary under a key.";
dictHasKeyQ::usage = 
        "dictHasKeyQ[dictionary, key] gives True if key in dictionary has not unset.";
dictKeyEmptyQ::usage =
        "dictKeyEmptyQ[dictionary, key] gives True if the value of key in dictionary is an empty list.";
dictKeys::usage =
        "dictKeys[dictionary] returns all keys in a dictionary.";
dictKeyValuePairs::usage =
        "dictKeyValuePairs[dictionary] returns all key value pairs in a dictionary.";

Begin["`Private`"]

makeDictionary[]:=Module[{name},
name=Unique["dict"];
Evaluate[name][k_]:={};
Dictionary[name]
]
destroyDictionary[Dictionary[name_,___]]:=If[ValueQ[name[_]],Remove[name];True,False]
dictName[Dictionary[name_,___]]:=name
dictStore[dict_Dictionary,key_,value_]:=Module[{d=dictName[dict]},d[key]=Prepend[d[key],value]]
dictReplace[dict_Dictionary,key_,value_]:=Module[{d=dictName[dict]},d[key]=Union[d[key],{value}]]
dictRemove[dict_Dictionary,key_,value_]:=Module[{d=dictName[dict]},d[key]=Complement[d[key],{value}]]
dictLookup[Dictionary[name_,___],key_]:=name[key]
dictHasKeyQ[Dictionary[name_,___],key_]:=ValueQ[name[key]]
dictKeyEmptyQ[Dictionary[name_,___],key_]:=name[key]==={}
dictKeys[dict_Dictionary]:=Most[DownValues[Evaluate@dictName[dict]]]/.HoldPattern[a_:>values_List]:>a[[1,1]]
dictKeyValuePairs[dict_Dictionary]:=Most[DownValues[Evaluate[dictName[dict]]]]/.HoldPattern[a_:>values_List]:>{a[[1,1]],values}
Dictionary[name_][prop_] := With[{d = dictLookup[Dictionary[name], prop]}, If[Length@d == 1, First@d, d]]

End[ ]

EndPackage[ ]
```

A basic example:

```
sweden = {"Gothenburg", "Stockholm", "Kalmar", "Halmstad"};
unitedstates = {"Clinton", "Terre Haute", "Springfield", 
   "St. Louis"};
cities = makeDictionary[];
dictStore[cities, "Sweden", #] & /@ sweden;
dictStore[cities, "United States", #] & /@ unitedstates;

dictKeys[cities]
```

> `{"Sweden", "United States"}`

```
dictLookup[cities, "United States"]
```

> `{"St. Louis", "Springfield", "Terre Haute", "Clinton"}`

I've added a shorthand for dictLookup, so that you can retrieve a property easily by just writing `dictionary["prop"]`.