# How do I find the number of countries that have a type of industry?

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data

I am trying to find the number of countries that have a certain type of industry.

Currently, I have this code:

```
countries = Flatten[CountryData[]];

listofCountries = Table[countries[[i]], {i, 1, 240}];

industries = Map[{CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"]} &, CountryData[All]];

data = Table[industries[[i]] -> listofCountries[[i]], {i, 1, 240}];
```

I am not sure on how to find the number of countries that have an industry (i.e. `Coal`), or if I am headed in the correct direction.

Could somebody show me the correct way to find the number of countries with an industry?

EDIT: If I were trying to shade in the countries found on the world map with a color, how would I do so? (This is using the CountryData function.) I'm curious to see how much of the world has this industry, and so forth. (EDIT: How could I do it with the world map showing the boundaries of every country?)

EDIT 2: How could I do the edit above with two industries? (i.e. Coal and Copper)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
Select[CountryData[], 
  Not @ FreeQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"] &] // Length
```

> `13`

OR

```
Cases[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"] & /@ CountryData, {___, "Coal", ___}] // Length
```

You can also display the countries in question:

```
Select[countries, 
 Not[FreeQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"]] &]
```

Here they are:

```
{"Afghanistan", "BosniaHerzegovina", "China", "Colombia", "Germany", \
"Kazakhstan", "Nigeria", "Poland", "Russia", "Swaziland", "Ukraine", \
"UnitedKingdom", "Vietnam"}
```

If you want to visualize them as in your edited question, do the following:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], If[MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"], Red, LightBrown],
CountryData[#, "SchematicPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

[image]

To address your final edit:

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black],
    Which[MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"], Red,
          MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Copper"], Blue,
          True, White], CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"]} & /@ CountryData[]]
```

[image]

Here, red represents coal countries and blue represents copper countries. To get the number of countries that have either coal or copper industry do:

```
Select[countries, MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"] || 
   MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Copper"] &] // Length
```

This gives:

> `20`

Comment: Thanks! How would I do the question I edited in?

Comment: @user9876 See my edit.

Comment: Is coal really one of the UK's major industries? I thought the government had [closed it down](http://www.geographyinthenews.rgs.org/news/article/?id=273)...

Comment: @cormullion, I guess Wolfram needs to update their data.

Comment: Two more questions (edited in). First, how can I include the border of all the countries? Second, how can I do this, but with two industries instead of one?

Comment: @user9876, see my new answer. Also what do you mean by two industries? Do you want only countries that have both industries or you want to display countries that have at least one of those industries?

Comment: Wouldn't `MemberQ` be easier than `Not[FreeQ[...]]`?

Comment: @kirma, I actually used `MemberQ` in my `Graphics` section. Just felt like using `FreeQ`

Comment: @RunnyKine OK. Just wondering, what calamity is behind disappearance of Alaska on these maps? :)

Comment: @kirma, I think Russia took back their land. :)

Comment: Some weird copper data which makes you lose some faith in the sources -- best to use primary sources for serious work I think. Peru is the second biggest producer and not mentioned. We have Zambia but not Congo etc.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I noticed the "CIA World Factbook" did the same thing. Didn't mention copper for Peru, but did mention "mining". And if you look up mining in `CountryData`, then indeed Peru is included. So perhaps it's the way people who work with stats categorize  things that isn't intuitive, it doesn't mean it's not correct/up to date The factbook puts copper in the mining category for Congo as well, but puts "copper mining" on its own for Zambia.

Comment: @kirma So it seems using `FullPolygon` brings back Alaska.

Comment: @anon We need the NSA factbook, they know everything...

Answer (score 7):

We can approach this with **v10** functionalities quite nicely:

```
countries = EntityList@EntityClass["Country", "Countries"];
coal = Select[countries, MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Coal"] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use `Length` to get the number if so desired.

```
copper = Select[countries, MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Copper"] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], GeoStyling["OutlineMap", Red], 
  Polygon[coal], GeoStyling["OutlineMap", Blue], Polygon[copper]}, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR without background:

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[countries], 
  GeoStyling["OutlineMap", Red], Polygon[coal], 
  GeoStyling["OutlineMap", Blue], Polygon[copper]}, ImageSize -> 800, 
 GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

```
Count[Flatten[
  CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"] & /@ CountryData[]], "Coal"]
```

> 13

Answer (score 4):

Your first approach, using rules, I think is not a bad idea. Here's one way to implement a rules-based solution:

```
hasIndustry[industry_] := Select[CountryData[], MemberQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], industry] &]
industries = Union @@ (CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"] & /@ CountryData[] /. _Missing -> Sequence[]);
countryIndustries = Dispatch[# -> hasIndustry[#] & /@ industries];
```

This sets up a list of rules such that `"Coal" /. countryIndustries` returns all countries that have coal as a major industry. We've used `Dispatch` on the list so it should be super fast.

Utilitary functions:

```
hasEither[list_List] := Union @@ (# /. countryIndustries & /@ list)
hasAll[list_List] := Intersection @@ (# /. countryIndustries & /@ list)
```

So to sum it up, if we want to know what countries have `x` as a major industry, we used `hasIndustry`. If we want to know all the countries to have any of `{x,y,z}` as a major industry, we used `hasEither` and if we want to select only the countries that have all of `{x,y,z}` as major industries we use `hasAll`.

```
hasAll[{"Carpets", "BuildingMaterials"}]
```

> `{"Afghanistan", "Nepal"}`

To know how many countries fulfill a certain criteria, we simply use `Length` the same way RunnyKine has.

RunnyKine has already provided a great answer, I'm just sort of recreating it but differently for the fun of it. So I wrote this as well:

```
bg = Graphics[{
    RGBColor[0.896`, 0.8878`, 0.8548`], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]],
    CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ CountryData[]
    }, ImageSize -> 1000];
highlight[industry_] := Graphics[{
    Red, EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0]],
    CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ hasIndustry[industry]
    }];
Manipulate[Show[bg, highlight[industry]], {industry, industries}]
```

[image: map]

I wrote another post that deals with maps and interactivity, that you may be interested in. You can find it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33207/how-to-embed-graphic-element-specific-metadata-within-a-graphics-object/33411#33411).