# How do I get a list of all the wine producing countries using V11?

Tags: curated-data, geography, wolfram-alpha-queries

I have tried several options and although I have looked at Wolfram Alpha snippets, I cannot get those to work in V11.

This link is the best I could find, but I cannot replicate it for wine, or wine grapes.

[How do I find the number of countries that have a type of industry?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33579/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-countries-that-have-a-type-of-industry/60251#60251?newreg=6fd70f246a0e437fa8898bb099e131df)

Any help much appreciated.  I last worked in MM7
Henk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WolframAlpha["wine producing countries", 
{{"PropertyRanking:AgricultureData", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
 PodStates -> {"PropertyRanking:AgricultureData__More"}]

(*  {{{1, "Italy", Quantity[5.287*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {2, 
   "Spain", Quantity[5.079*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {3, 
   "France", Quantity[4.733*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {4, 
   "United States", 
   Quantity[3.638*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {5, "China", 
   Quantity[1.874*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {6, "Argentina", 
   Quantity[1.652*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {7, "Chile", 
   Quantity[1.338*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {8, "Australia", 
   Quantity[1.308*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {9, "South Africa",
    Quantity[1.263*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {10, "Germany", 
   Quantity[1.014*10^6, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {11, "Portugal", 
   Quantity[665054, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {12, "Romania", 
   Quantity[416986, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {13, "Greece", 
   Quantity[368503, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {14, "Russia", 
   Quantity[360897, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {15, "New Zealand", 
   Quantity[353181, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {16, "Brazil", 
   Quantity[301041, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {17, "Hungary", 
   Quantity[284970, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {18, "Austria", 
   Quantity[220318, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {19, "Serbia", 
   Quantity[218459, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {20, "Moldova", 
   Quantity[165181, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {21, "Bulgaria", 
   Quantity[143852, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {22, "Georgia", 
   Quantity[119711, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {23, "Switzerland", 
   Quantity[102917, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {24, "Ukraine", 
   Quantity[95795, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {25, "Japan", 
   Quantity[93696, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {26, "Peru", 
   Quantity[80469, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {27, "Uruguay", 
   Quantity[79918, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {28, "Canada", 
   Quantity[60256, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {29, "Czech Republic", 
   Quantity[57320, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {30, "Algeria", 
   Quantity[57320, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {31, "Macedonia", 
   Quantity[56232, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {32, "Croatia", 
   Quantity[49904, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {33, "Turkey", 
   Quantity[49281, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {34, "Mexico", 
   Quantity[43387, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {35, "Turkmenistan", 
   Quantity[42990, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {36, "Morocco", 
   Quantity[40786, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {37, "Uzbekistan", 
   Quantity[39683, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {38, "Slovakia", 
   Quantity[35855, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {39, "Belarus", 
   Quantity[33047, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {40, "Kazakhstan", 
   Quantity[24243, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {41, "Tunisia", 
   Quantity[23700, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {42, "Albania", 
   Quantity[19290, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {43, "Montenegro", 
   Quantity[17637, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {44, "Lebanon", 
   Quantity[16204, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {45, "Slovenia", 
   Quantity[14582, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {46, "Colombia", 
   Quantity[14330, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {47, "Luxembourg", 
   Quantity[13772, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {48, "Cuba", 
   Quantity[13316, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {49, "Estonia", 
   Quantity[12240, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {50, "Cyprus", 
   Quantity[11356, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {51, "Azerbaijan", 
   Quantity[10485, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {52, "Bolivia", 
   Quantity[10386, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {53, "Madagascar", 
   Quantity[9204, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {54, 
   "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
   Quantity[8294, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {55, "Armenia", 
   Quantity[6806, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {56, "Lithuania", 
   Quantity[6619, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {57, "Israel", 
   Quantity[5512, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {58, "Egypt", 
   Quantity[5512, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {59, "Belgium", 
   Quantity[3197, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {60, "Libya", 
   Quantity[2910, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {61, "Latvia", 
   Quantity[2701, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {62, "Malta", 
   Quantity[2674, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {63, "Zimbabwe", 
   Quantity[1929, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {64, "Kyrgyzstan", 
   Quantity[1874, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {65, "Paraguay", 
   Quantity[1653, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {66, "Ethiopia", 
   Quantity[1430, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {67, "Jordan", 
   Quantity[606.3, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {68, "United Kingdom", 
   Quantity[468.5, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {69, "Panama", 
   Quantity[175.3, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {70, "Tajikistan", 
   Quantity[165.3, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {71, "Liechtenstein", 
   Quantity[87.08, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {72, "Syria", 
   Quantity[77.16, ("ShortTons")/("Years")]}, {73, "Réunion", 
   Quantity[33.07, ("ShortTons")/(
    "Years")]}}, "1969, 2013, and 2014 estimates"}  *)
```

Comment: Excellent!  This shows me how to use Wolfram Alpha directly.  Two countries are missing though, Mianmar and Thailand if I am not mistaken.  Still, this is the best approach for this specific problem it seems.  Question is, how can I do exactly this from Mathematica without using Alpha?  (Without calling as above?)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[CountryData[], 
 Not@FreeQ[CountryData[#, "MajorIndustries"], "Wine"] &]
```

{Entity["Country", "Georgia"], 
 Entity["Country", "Lebanon"], 
 Entity["Country", "Portugal"], 
 Entity["Country", "SanMarino"]}

Presumably "MajorIndustries" selects the largest $n$ industries in the country and for France, Italy, USA, etc., viticulture (as distinct from "Food") does not lie in that top $n$.

For instance,

```
CountryData[Entity["Country", "France"], "MajorIndustries"]
```

yields

(* {"Aircraft", "Automobiles", "Chemicals", "Electronics", "Food", "Machinery", "Metals", "Textiles", "Tourism"} *)

(notice these are in alphabetical order) and

```
CountryData[Entity["Country", "Italy"], "MajorIndustries"]
```

yields

(* {"Automobiles", "Ceramics", "Chemicals", "Clothing", "Food", "Iron",
"Machinery", "Metals", "Shoes", "Textiles", "Tourism"} *)

We can be sure that the returned order is not ranked by commercial value by this example:

```
CountryData[Entity["Country", "SaudiArabia"], "MajorIndustries"]
```

(* {"AircraftRepairs", "Ammonia", "BuildingMaterials", "Construction", 
"Fertilizer", "IndustrialGases", "Metals", "Oil", "Petrochemicals", 
"Plastics", "ShipRepair", "SodiumHydroxide"} *)

which lists "Ammonia" far before "Oil".

Comment: There's also `"ExportCommodities"`

Comment: Even `ExportCommodities` does not list wine (or even food) for France.

Comment: Unfortunate, but it does pick up Chile :P

Comment: Yes, this is actually a problem, so although the data is curated in some form, it is not very coherent.  Just wait until France discovers that wine is not a major thing!  Thanks, this does help a lot though.

Comment: The University of Adelaide has an extensive document on wien producing countries.  It would be cool to get that into Wolfram.