# How to Check Spelling strings written inside input cells

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to check the spelling of strings? Strings are often used to show messages in my user interfaces, and I would like to have an automatic checking.

Methods that export all the strings to a different notebook are also fine (if it can help). In this case, extracting things like \n would be a plus.

Comment: Not quite clear on exactly what you're looking for, but something like 

`(Pick[#, DictionaryLookup[#, IgnoreCase -> True] & /@ #, {}]) &[
 StringSplit["this is a yourr stringg"]]`

will return all words in the string not found in the MM dictionary.

Comment: Spontaneously I feel that if you want to work with your strings like that you shouldn't embed them in your code. Use the [dictionary data structure](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/implementing-a-dictionary-data-structure) or some other way to store your strings so that you can easily retrieve them for export.

Comment: @rasher I simply mean to be able to find spelling mistakes in the middle of input cells, by means of the menu "check spelling". When running it on a notebook, it finds all my mistakes, except inside input cells... Most likely to avoid finding all the user variables, name of functions, etc. To this I agree. But most strings in my code should have some checking.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, but after comment edit time-out. As you're aware, there's no built-in for that. You could use the notebook read functions and parse it yourself, or if acceptable, use some 'marker' comments around desired strings, and then just parse the notebook for what they bracket. I think the best way (biased - it's what I do) is to have the strings in a list, indexing to them where I use them. That way, I can run the quick dictionary check against the list entries.

Comment: @Anon I sometimes do gather all my strings together. But the notion of Manipulate is simplicity and fast... And so, when I do a simple Manipulate in the middle of a meeting (I really do!) I'm not thinking on data structures... And a quick check before putting it into the big screen would be nice. For know, passing all to MS Word is a little to cumbersome...

Comment: @rasher thank you for you suggestion. I do this for bigger apps, specially for translation purposes. But for smaller stuff... Please see my reply to Anon.