# Spelling check for InputField

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, options, customization

Is it possible to enable `ShowAutoSpellCheck` for `String` `InputFields`? Similarly to

```
Panel @ TextCell[
  "errorrr", ShowAutoSpellCheck -> True, LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage"
]
```

[image]

I failed to find a top level way to do this and I struggle with implementation of manual checks, or rather with making result `InputField` friendly:

```
mark = Style[#, FontVariations -> {"Underlight" -> Red}, 
    ShowStringCharacters -> False, StripOnInput -> True] &;

check[s_String] := StringRiffle[
   If[DictionaryWordQ[#], #, ToString[mark[#], StandardForm]
      ] & /@ StringSplit[s],
   " "
   ];

x = check@"test errr test"

InputField[Dynamic[x], String]
```

[image]

Looks nice but does not work anymore. This boils down to 'how to create styled strings which can be edited in an InputField'. But I don't claim it is the only what to achieve the goal here.

Any tips?

---

This topic [How to Check Spelling strings written inside input cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40199/5478) is very similar but I think it can be solved, with a some effort, because Format/Style items work on strings in input cells but not in `InputField`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to use the built-in autocomplete:

```
s = "wut";
Panel@
 InputField[
  Dynamic[
   TextCell[s,
    ShowAutoStyles -> True,
    ShowAutoSpellCheck -> True, 
    LanguageCategory -> "NaturalLanguage",
    Editable -> True
    ],
   Replace[
    {
     TextCell[str_, ___] :> Set[s, str],
     _ :> Set[s, ""]
     }
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

[image: asdasdasd]

It's kinda buggy when editing though

Comment: In my experience the whole `InputField` function is extremely buggy each time I wanted to do something a bit more complicated and user-friendly. `InputField` really needs a complete overhaul in order to be really usable.

Comment: For me it never stores entered string, shows it and when the focus is lost `"wut"` is back. So kinda too buggy for me :P