# Does Mathematica support an unordered set (e.g. hashset) data structure?

Tags: data-structures

Does *Mathematica* support any data structure representing an unordered set (without multiplicity) of *Mathematica* expressions? I would like this data structure to support $O(1)$ insertion, deletion, and membership testing.

Note that according to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/9972), `Association`s only support $O(\log n)$ insertion and deletion.

Comment: I think that for all practical purposes, you can consider `Association` to have `O(1)`  complexity for all those operations. The point is that, implementing on the top-level any such structure would lead to constant factors far greater that `log n` for any sensible size of the set. You can also try ``System`Utilities`HashTable``, described in e.g. [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/1029#1029).

Answer (score 2):

`DeleteDuplicates` is another way to build sets, or, more precisely,  ordered lists with no duplicates (a friend of mine calls such things "suits," I think a brilliant name).  Note the last little minitest here fails:

```
{DeleteDuplicates[{}],
 DeleteDuplicates[{1}] == DeleteDuplicates[{1, 1}],
 DeleteDuplicates[{2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}] == 
  DeleteDuplicates[{1, 2, 3}]}
```

> ```
> {{}, True, False}
> ```

Easy to fix by composing with `Sort`:

```
ClearAll[set];
set = Sort@*DeleteDuplicates;
{set[{}],
 set[{1}] == set[{1, 1}],
 set[{2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}] == set[{1, 2, 3}]}
```

> ```
> {{}, True, True}
> ```

Here's a specific implementation of the ideas in Leonid's comment:

```
ClearAll[set];
set[l_List] := Sort@Keys@Association@MapThread[Rule, {l, l}];
{set[{}],
 set[{1}] == set[{1, 1}],
 set[{2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1}] == set[{1, 2, 3}]}
```

> ```
> {{}, True, True}
> ```

Keep or remove the `Sort` depending on whether you want a set or a suit. However, the `Sort` introduces more overhead, getting you away from (close to) O(1) perf, as you requested.

**EDIT**: The difference between set and suit can be important if you're trying to emulate a combinatorial function like `Permutations`. This function treats duplicate elements as identical, but it is also 'stable', meaning that it doesn't change the orders of inputs. If you try to emulate it using a set instead of a suit, you can get a scrambled answer. For instance, consider

```
Permutations[{1, 1, 1, 0, 0}] // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}

Let's make our own `permutations` that can take a `collector` function as an input, and try it out with `suit` to check that we get the same answer, in the same order, as with the built-in `Permutations`:

```
ClearAll[permutations, set, suit];
set[l_List] := Sort@Keys@Association@MapThread[Rule, {l, l}];
suit[l_List] := Keys@Association@MapThread[Rule, {l, l}];
permutations[collector_, {}] := {{}};
permutations[collector_, xs_List] :=
  collector[
   Flatten[
    Table[
     With[{
       x = xs[[i]],
       plucked = Join[xs[[;; i - 1]], xs[[i + 1 ;;]]]},
      Prepend[x] /@ permutations[collector, plucked]],
     {i, Length[xs]}],
    1]];

permutations[suit, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}] // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}

Now try it with `set` as the collector:

```
permutations[set, {1, 1, 1, 0, 0}] // TeXForm
```

\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}