# Assigning to multiple variables in a list the values in another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, one contains the variables and the other the corresponding values that the variables should take.

```
letters = {"a","m","t","h","e"}
bonus = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
words = {math, the, gps, log}
```

I know that this works (as in the manual of Mathematica):

```
{a,b,c} = {10,20,30}
```

But the lists are rather long, so I would like to write:

```
letters = bonus
```

Which does not work.
Output: I would like to have the variables (letters) taking the values (bonus) a=10, b=20, c=30.
Having the weight of the letters, it should be possible to compute the weight of every word in list "words" [math (100), the (120) etc.]
I would appreciate some pointers to get me started. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The items in your "letters" `List` are `Strings` not `Symbols` and therefore can't be assigned values. You might be better off creating a `Rule` for the letter values.

Comment: You can try `Clear[letters]; Evaluate@(Symbol /@ letters) = bonus`. This will create symbols from your strings, then assign them a value, i.e. `a=10` etc. Beware that the `Clear` bit is important if you plan to run this code more than once. Notice, however, that you are NOT assigning a value TO THE STRING `"a"`, but to the symbol `a`. This may still not work for what you want. An `Association` construct would probably work a lot better.

Comment: @Xavier, @Quantum_Oli, @garej - I used `"// Timing"` to time the processes. The three answers below demand different times with a dictionary of about 240 thousand words. Plus: 0.005087, Total: 0.013299 and Map: 0.039653. The Plus solution is thus the quickest.

Answer (score 5):

Using associations:

```
letters = {"a","m","t","h","e"};
bonus = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
words = {math, the, gps, log};

assoc = AssociationThread[letters -> bonus];

Plus @@@ (Lookup[assoc, #, 0] & /@ Characters[ToString /@ words])

(* {100, 120, 0, 0} *)
```

If the words are strings, rather than symbols, then simply `Characters[words]` instead of `Characters[ToString /@ words]`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay before responding, I have been travelling. Thank you @Xavier, It works like a charm. I have to understand Associations. Every time I get here I learn something.

Comment: Re: associations -- You may find this [post (52393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations) useful.

Answer (score 3):

Converting your words to strings first:

```
    letters = {"a", "m", "t", "h", "e"}
    bonus = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}
    words = {"math", "the", "gps", "log"}
```

We can create a list of rules for the values of letters (rather than assign values to many variables):

```
    Thread[letters -> bonus]
```

> {"a" -> 10, "m" -> 20, "t" -> 30, "h" -> 40, "e" -> 50}

Then we can use `Characters` to split each word into a list of it's characters:

```
    Characters /@ words
```

> {{"m", "a", "t", "h"}, {"t", "h", "e"}, {"g", "p", "s"}, {"l", "o", 
>     "g"}}

Putting it all together:

```
    Total /@ ((Characters /@ words) /. Thread[letters -> bonus])
```

> {100, 120, "g" + "p" + "s", "g" + "l" + "o"}

Comment: Sorry for the delay before responding, I have been travelling. Thank you @Quantum_Oli, It works like a charm. Every time I get here I learn something. It is especially useful with such a pedagogical explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
letters = {"a", "m", "t", "h", "e"};
bonus = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
words = {math, the, gps, log};
```

Solution:

```
Map[Total @ Replace[#, Append[Thread[letters -> bonus], _ -> 0], 1] &,
Characters[ToString /@ words]]
```

> {100, 120, 0, 0}

Comment: Thank you @garey, it also works nicely. I will try to find the timings for all three solutions (if I can do that). I do not understand the `"_->0"`. Where can I read about it? Thanks.

Comment: @JSP, This is a [pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html) with `Rule`. You may see that `Raplace` expects a pattern as an option. So your `letter->score` are simple replacement rules that applied first. Then `_->0` construct applies (it replaces all the rest letters in characters list). It means "replace any symbol to `0`". Here `_` is blank and stands for any symbol.