# List, Association, and Dataset, according to what principles to choose which one to use?

Tags: data, dataset, associations, data-structures, data-acquisition

`List`, `Association` and `Dataset` are three 'objects' that can be used to store data in *MMA*. So when or under what conditions for one to decide to use each of them?

Comment: This is a good start: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54493/5478

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot!