# How does one create getter methods that depend on a variable (besides its argument)?

Tags: data-structures

In the (as always) insigthful answer by Leonard Shifrin to this MMA SE post

[`https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations.html)

the `makePersonInfoMutable` struct implementation deals with the case where there are two struct members, corresponding to the arguments `fname` and `lname`. I wanted to extend the code to deal with the case of a variable number of struct members, with both the member names (`fnames`) and member data (`lnames`) passed as arguments. (I was actually thinking of the case where the second argument would be a list of real numbers, but the exact nature of the second argument is not relevant). The code below, mostly copied from Mr. Shifrin's answer, shows the issue:

```
ClearAll[makePersonInfoMutable];
makePersonInfoMutable[fname_, lname_, fnames_List, lnames_List] := 
  Module[{fn = fname, ln = lname, fns = fnames, lns = lnames, 
    instance},
   SetAttributes[instance, HoldAll];
   instance[getFirstName[]] := fn;
   instance[getLName[fns[1]][]] := lns[[1]];
   instance@setFirstName[name_] := fn = name;
   instance@getLastName[] := ln;
   instance@setLastName[name_] := ln = name;
   instance@getFullName[] := fn <> " " <> ln;
   instance];
pinfo = makePersonInfoMutable["Leonard", 
   "Shifrin", {"Joe", "Mary"}, {"Smith", "Jackson"}];
pinfo@getFirstName[]
(*  Leonard  *)
pinfo[getLName["Joe"][]]
(*  instance$1356[getName["Joe"][]]  *)
```

I only added two lines the original code. The first one, inside the `Module`, is

```
instance[getName[fns[1]][]] := lns[[1]];
```

(I used `1` as the index, but more generally this could be `i` within a `Do` command, or something similar.)

The second added line of code,

```
pinfo[getLName["Joe"][]]
```

and its output show I did not get what I expected, which would be

```
(* Smith  *)
```

For comparison, I placed this second added line just below the similar command in the original post, which of course works fine.

I am sure there is a way to do this, but I cannot figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**

The temporary symbol `instance$...` created by `makePersonInfoMutable` is `HoldAll`,

```
pinfo = makePersonInfoMutable["Leonard", "Shifrin", {"Joe", "Mary"}, {"Smith", "Jackson"}];

Attributes[instance$298]
(* {HoldAll, Temporary} *)
```

Because of this attribute, the additional line of code

```
instance[getLName[fns[[1]]][]] := lns[[1]];
```

creates a definition with the subexpression `fns$...[[1]]`,

```
Cases[DownValues[instance$298], 
    def : HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][_[getLName[_][]]] :> _] :> def
]
(* {HoldPattern[instance$298[getLName[fns$298[[1]]][]]] :> lns$298[[1]]} *)
```

instead of creating it with `"Joe"` (where `"Joe"` is `fns$298[[1]]`). This means that no definition exists for `pinfo[getLName["Joe"][]]`, and this is why it is returned unevaluated. Note, on the contrary, that this evaluates:

```
pinfo[getLName[fns$298[[1]]][]]
(* "Smith" *)
```

since the held argument of `pinfo` matches the definition.

**Solution**

A possible solution is to make the subexpression evaluate before giving it to the definition. This can be done by changing the additional line of code to

```
With[{fs = fns[[1]]}, instance[getLName[fs][]] := lns[[1]]];
```

which then gives the expected output:

```
pinfo = makePersonInfoMutable["Leonard", "Shifrin", {"Joe", "Mary"}, {"Smith", "Jackson"}];

pinfo[getLName["Joe"][]]
(* "Smith" *)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works. Beginner's questions: 1) Why does the problem remain if the SetAttributes line is removed, 2) Why doesn't `instance[getLName[Evaluate@fns[1]][]] := lns[[1]];` fix the problem?, 3) In `pinfo[getLName[fns$298[[1]]][]]` I guess the execution is already outside `Module`, since pinfo is already defined. If that is the case, how is fns$XXX available?, 4) If you wrap a `Do` around the `With[{...}]` statement, even leaving `1` in place instead of `i` the problem reappears. Why?

Comment: The Do problem I mentioned in the previous comment can be solved by `Do[With[{fs = fns[[i]], j = i}, 
  instance[getLName[fs][]] := lns[[j]]], {i, n}]`

Comment: 1) It works fine, but you need to change `fns[1]` to `fns[[1]]`. You have a typo in the code. 2) The `Evaluate` would be too deep. You would need instead (with the `SetAttributes` kept, otherwise it is not useful): `instance[Evaluate@getLName[fns[[1]]][]] := lns[[1]]`. (Note that the type is corrected here as well.) 3) The variable `fns$XXX` is created as soon as the `Module` is called, so it can be accessed outside its scope.

Comment: Indeed it works without HoldAll and the typo corrected. That being the case, should I get rid of the SetAttributes line?

Comment: The `HoldAll` attribute may not be useful in this short version of the code, so it can probably be removed.