# Speed Up Creating a List of Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, performance

### Background

I frequently import data from CSV files. This data often has headers, is a mix of numbers and text, and is a simple 2D 'shape'. I need to clean the data (eg removing rows, trimming strings, standardizing units etc.) before I can work with it.

My strategy is to convert it to a `List` of `Association`s which makes cleaning and manipulation easier.

### Table to Association

I built a function to convert tables with headers into an association.

```
ta[table_List] := AssociationThread[First[table], #] & /@ Rest[table];
```

For example:

```
smallTable = {{"a1", "a2"}, {1, 2}, {3, "Four"}};
ta[smallTable]
```

> {<|"a1" -> 1, "a2" -> 2|>, <|"a1" -> 3, "a2" -> "Four"|>}

**Question: Can this code go any faster?**

Let's see how it performs on a larger table

```
(*make table*)
rows = 100000;
cols = 100;

SeedRandom[100];
data = RandomReal[1, {rows, cols}];
data[[1]][[1]] = "TEXT";

header = WordList[][[1 ;; cols]];
table = Join[{header}, data];
```

```
assc = ta[table]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.78668, Null}

---

### My attempts

Here is my attempt at making this faster using `MapThread`

```
ta2[table_List] :=
  MapThread[
   AssociationThread,
   {
    ConstantArray[First[table], Length[Rest[table]]],
    Rest[table]
    }
   ];

assc2 = ta2[table]; // RepeatedTiming
assc2 === assc
```

> {1.78114, Null}

> True

Almost no improvement

---

Now trying to see if localising the variable helps...

```
ta3[table_List] :=
  With[
   {
    values = Rest[table],
    headers = First[table]
    },
   With[
    {
     keys = ConstantArray[headers, Length[values]]
     },
    MapThread[AssociationThread, {keys, values}]
    ]
   ];

assc3 = ta3[table]; // RepeatedTiming
assc3 === assc
```

> {1.72666, Null}

> True

Virtually no improvement again

---

Is it faster making a list of `Rules` and then mapping `Association` on it...?

```
ta4[table_List] :=
  With[
   {
    keys = ConstantArray[First[table], Length[Rest[table]]],
    values = Rest[table]
    },
   Map[Association, MapThread[Rule, {keys, values}, 2], 2]
   ];

assc4 = ta4[table]; // RepeatedTiming
assc4 === assc
```

> {10.0572, Null}

> True

...it is not

---

I have also tried `ParallelMap` with `AssociationThread[First[table], #] &` but this is incredibly slow.

Comment: I tried `Inner[Rule, table[[1]], #, Association]& /@ table[[2;;All]]`, but this is not faster than your ta[ ].

Comment: Maybe you could try directly importing the CSV as a `Dataset` with `SemanticImport`? I do not know if this will be faster however. Ex: `imported = SemanticImport["yourCSV.csv"] // Normal;`

Comment: Also, as another option, you could create a paired list instead of a list of associations and do all your manipulations with that instead. `Thread[{First@table, #}] & /@ Rest[table]; // RepeatedTiming` is about 05-0.6 s . But there may be a good reason you want a list of associations like you have in `assc`

Comment: An alternative: `Table[AssociationThread @@ ({table[[1]], table[[i]]}), {i, 2, Length[table]}]`

Comment: perhaps try `Import["yourCSVfile", "Dataset",  "HeaderLines" -> 1]`?

Comment: See [TableSet](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TableSet)

Comment: possibly related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149547/how-to-efficiently-write-into-packedarrays-that-are-stored-in-associations

Answer (score 5):

I find `Association` (and `Dataset`) are too heavy for tabular data. Try [`TableSet`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/TableSet).

`TableSet` supports `Query`, `JoinAcross`, and many other SQL-like functions. Named `Slot`s are used so you get `Association`-like data manipulation in `Query`. Also, it uses much less memory than `Association`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (+1) Nice Resource Function, @Edmund!

Comment: Thank you Edmund, let me see how I can incorporate this into my existing project where I already make extensive use of `Associations`

Comment: I think I'm missing something obvious but how do you extract the column values using the column name in `TableSet`? ie analogous to `assoc[[All,"ColName"]]`