# Timing: extracting from List VS extracting from Association

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations

I was wondering, why is extracting from an `Association` slightly faster than extracting from a `List`?

```
assoc = Association[Table[i -> i^2, {i, 1000}]];
list = Table[i^2, {i, 1000}];
list[[10]] // RepeatedTiming
assoc[10] // RepeatedTiming
(* I'm not posting outputs because of the variance but the 2nd is usually faster *)
```

I would have expected nothing to be faster than extraction from a `List` since it should be just a memory access vs a more computationally-expensive lookup for `Association`.

MMA 11.2 Linux.

Comment: I was going to mention something about unpacking, but the version using ``ulst = Developer`FromPackedArray[list]`` is even slower. Huh.

Comment: I am not convinced that association-lookup is really faster.  It could be some timing artefact. It is not easy to time such extremely short operations accurately.  `list[[#]] & /@ Range[100]` is 9 times *faster* on my machine than `assoc /@ Range[100]`.

Comment: The benchmark in my comment above is flawed. `Part` is faster because of auto-compilation.  Change `Range[100]` to `Range[99]` and association lookup becomes almost precisely 2x faster than list indexing. I wonder if it has any significance that the factor is almost precisely 2.

Comment: `Lookup[assoc, 10]` is consistently a little faster than `assoc[10]` for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that Mathematica is an interpreter language, so there is significant overhead in each single call. Only bulk access to data can show that `List`s are significantly faster than `Association`s.

```
n = 1000;
assoc = AssociationThread[Range[n], Range[n]^2];
list = Range[n]^2;
idx = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 100000];
Do[x = list[[i]], {i, idx}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[y = assoc[i], {i, idx}]; // AbsoluteTiming
a = Table[assoc[i], {i, idx}]; // AbsoluteTiming
b = Table[list[[i]], {i, idx}]; // AbsoluteTiming
c = list[[idx]]; // AbsoluteTiming
d = Lookup[assoc, idx]; // AbsoluteTiming
a == b == c == d
```

> {0.047621, Null}
>
> {0.044828, Null}
>
> {0.029103, Null}
>
> {0.001618, Null}
>
> {0.000347, Null}
>
> {0.008003, Null}
>
> True

(Mathematica 11.3 for macos)

Comment: If you have time, could you add a few words on how a dictionary (or association) is implemented? That would be very interesting! I'm also interested in the overhead during a list call. I could probably find this online with a deeper search so don't feel forced :)

Comment: Well, I am not an expert in dictionaries but the basic idea is to have a hash function `f` that maps keys to memory adresses. In order to lower the chances of collision, this hash function has to be rather "discontinuous", that means that `f[key1]` and `f[key2]` should map to different adresses, even if `key1` and `key2` are similar. Still, collision cannot completely avoided. So, compared to simple arrays, there is some overhead i) in computing `f[key]` and ii) in handling these collisions.

Comment: The advantage over `arrays` is that you do not have to rely on consecutive integer indices and that appending entries and dropping entries of a dictionary is of low cost.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "overhead during a list call". All I can say is that both `Part` and `Lookup` certainly have compiled libraries as backends and that the communication between the MathKernel and these libraries can be reduced by sending as few queries as possible.

Comment: Note that `Table[list[[i]]...]` is compiled, which greatly speeds up the performance, and there are differences in speed between packed and unpacked `list` and `idx`, for all four combinations. (Compilation can be prevented with ``SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> Infinity]``.)

Comment: @anderstood The Mathematica Association is a hash array mapped trie, per https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thank you for the great link!

Answer (score 1):

Association key-value pairs are indexed objects.  Lists are not.  As you increase the dimensionality of your association vs list comparison you will quickly see best practice is to put everything in associations and datasets.

Comment: That's not true - at least for purely numerical data.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher - right, but I can't remember the last time I worked pure numerical list, so my lack of qualification.  My context is n-dimensions with characteristic variables.  Since M10 Association and Dataset have been a valuable help to my work saving lots of custom work indexing data and cpu cycles working on the data.