# How to select elements from a list using another list

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have two lists: `list1` and `list2`:

```
list1 = {{"TSC" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", 22}, {"CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", 
21}, {"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "EGW", 20}, {"MA1" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", 
19}, {"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 18}, {"EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", 
17}, {"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 16}, {"CO12" \[DirectedEdge] "MA1", 
14}, {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 13}, {"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", 
12}, {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 11}, {"CST" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
10}, {"EST" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 9}, {"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", 
8}, {"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", 7}, {"EST" \[DirectedEdge] "MA1", 
6}, {"EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", 5}, {"CST" \[DirectedEdge] "EGW", 
4}, {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", 2}};

list2 = {"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", "AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", "FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 
"MA1" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", "FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
"EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC"};
```

I want to select those {x, y} pairs from `list1` using elements (x) in `list2`, and then take the average of the `y`s that are already selected. I like to do it in one-liner code.

I tried:

```
Mean[Select[list1, MemberQ[#, list2] &][[All,2]]]
```

with no success. I tried many other codes available in this forum but I cannot get what I want.

Comment: `Select[list1,MemberQ[list2,#[[1]]]&][[All,2]]`

Comment: @Lacia:Many thanks for the code. This solved my problem!!! If you put it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Which is the fastest?

Comment: @user5610:  some speed test results are given below (see @Lacia).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As shown by other answers, there are many solutions for one problem in Mathematica.

### List

`MemberQ`

```
Select[list1,MemberQ[list2,#[[1]]]&][[All,2]]//RepeatedTiming
(*{0.0000154381,{19,18,17,16,13,12,2}}*)

Cases[list1,{edge_,int_}/;MemberQ[list2,edge]:>int]//RepeatedTiming
(*{0.0000130373,{19,18,17,16,13,12,2}}*)
```

`Alternatives` is faster since it's purely a pattern

```
Cases[list1,{Alternatives@@list2,int_}:>int]//RepeatedTiming
(*{5.47926·10^-6,{19,18,17,16,13,12,2}}*)
```

### Set

`Intersection` has an option `SameTest`. The effect is that `Intersection[A,B,SameTest->f]` returns the intersection of `A` by `B` according to `f`

```
Intersection[list1,list2,SameTest->(First[#1]===#2&)][[All,2]]//RepeatedTiming
(*{0.000107458,{2,13,17,18,16,19,12}}*)
```

Notice that `Intersection` is a set-theoretical function, hence it breaks the original order and is slower.

### Association

This is realized by @Syed. In my experience, this approach is more suitable when dealing with dataset.

- The code is more readable/maintainable. If querying the data with more complicated requirements, the level specification in the list/set approach is much harder to track (imagine that there are lots of `[[All,1;;-1;;2]]`... )
- Association has better performance than List, see e.g. [How to make use of Associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations)
- support SQL-like operations, see `guide/DatabaseLikeOperationsOnDatasets`

For simple tasks there seems no significant difference between these two approaches.

Answer (score 5):

```
result = Rule @@@ list1 // KeyTake[list2] // Values
```

{12, 13, 2, 18, 19, 16, 17}

```
result // Mean
```

97/7

Comment: `Mean[list2 /. Rule @@@ list1]` suffices

Answer (score 3):

**Using `KeySelect`:**

```
asc1 = (First@# -> Last@#) & /@ list1
Values@KeySelect[asc1, MemberQ[list2, #] &]
```

> {19, 18, 17, 16, 13, 12, 2}

To get the mean:

```
Mean@Values@KeySelect[asc1, MemberQ[list2, #] &]
```

---

**Using `Position` and `Extract`:**

```
Extract[list1
   , Position[
    Position[list2, #] & /@ list1[[All, 1]]
    , Except[{}], 1, Heads -> False]
   ] // Map[Last] // Mean
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
f[rule_] := Map[If[MemberQ[#, rule], #, Nothing] &, list1];
lst = Flatten[Map[f[#] &, list2], 1]

(* {{"MA2" \[DirectedEdge] "AGF", 12}, {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
  13}, {"AGF" \[DirectedEdge] "CST", 
  2}, {"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "CO12", 
  18}, {"MA1" \[DirectedEdge] "FIN", 
  19}, {"FIN" \[DirectedEdge] "MA2", 
  16}, {"EGW" \[DirectedEdge] "TSC", 17}}  *)

Mean[Transpose[lst][[2]]]

(*  97/7  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

```
Extract[list1[[All,2]],Position[list1[[All,1]],Alternatives@@list2]]//Mean

(* 97/7 *)
```

Perhaps a more readable version:

```
 Extract[list1,Position[list1,Alternatives@@list2].{{1,0},{0,2}}]//Mean


 (* 97/7 *)
```

Or, using[`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) rather than [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html):

```
list1[[All,2]][[(list1//Position[Alternatives@@list2])[[All,1]]]]//Mean

(* 97/7 *)
```