# Association without an associated value

Tags: associations

Sometimes, we only need to store the keys which will be checked whether certain keys exist in the data structure(corresponding data structures in C++ are `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`). Despite the presence of the old posts such as 
[Implementing a dictionary data structure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/implementing-a-dictionary-data-structure) and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392007/is-there-hashtable-structure-in-wolfram-mathematica, now that we have `Association` since 10.0, I guess there must be a natural way using `Association` to achieve this goal.

Of course, one straightforward way might be to introduce an arbitrary expression as a value corresponding each key. However, I am searching for the most memory (or time) efficient way to do it. (i.e., I want to find a way to minimize the overhead due to this unnecessary value)

```
x = <| a -> "Garbage", b -> "Gabage"|>;
x[a]
x[c]

Out[1]= Garbage
Out[2]= Missing["KeyAbsent", c]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native MMA object to handle hashed sets yet. Meanwhile I use this approach:

```
x = <| a -> True, b -> True|>;
```

Now, for looking for elements we can do:

```
Lookup[x, a, False]
Lookup[x, c, False]
```

> `True`
>
> `False`

And for a lookup list:

```
Lookup[x,{a,b,c},False]
```

> `{True, True, False}`

Answer (score 3):

The approach of @Murta is the one I'm now using too.

I just want to add, for performance and memory concerns, that, when feasible,  sometimes, it is more efficient to store the elements **not** in the set, so practically reversing that approach.

More explicitely, if you know that the majority of the elements of a space $X$ are likely to belong to a subset $A \subset X$, it is more convenient to store in an `Association` the elements of $X-A$, i.e.  `Complement[X, A]`

```
C = <| a -> False, b -> False|>;
```

Then you reverse the lookup:

```
Lookup[C, a, True]
Lookup[C, c, True]
```

and you still get if the elements belongs to $A$ but more faster and with less memory consumed.