# How to use classical data structure in Mathematica

Tags: programming, data-structures

As a C programmer, I have used *Mathematica* for a month. In this process, I discovered that some problems cannot be solved via the built-ins, owing to lacking of data structure like `binary tree, quartic tree, half-edge`, etc. So I would like know how to use the classical data structure in Mathematica.

[image: quadtree]
[image: quadtree refinement]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica)

Comment: [Data Structures and Efficient Algorithms in Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/321/) by Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: @Nasser I can't figure out how to get to the content from your link? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @user6014 humm it was there when I looked at it long time ago first time. It seems Mathematica library archive is not being well maintained these days. I am sure there is a copy somewhere. But no time now to search....

Comment: @Nasser That's a shame. I appreciate the initial effort. I'll poke around and see what I can find. Thanks!

Comment: @Nasser I think [this talk (notebook included)](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/388/) by Daniel Lichtblau should come close if not to being identical to the one you posted?

Comment: Daniel also demonstrated a quadtree implementation using ``Internal`Bag[]`` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762). It only does quadtrees, but it is not too hard to modify to get it to do [octrees](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CbGza.png).

Comment: @gwr yes, that is the one. Thanks for finding it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here'a quad-tree index (trie) illustrating the compact codes and efficiency enabled by nested Associations and recursive Queries - no looping, no NestWhile or Fold is used.

Compare to earlier implementations, eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica#). Also addresses ["can a Trie be implemented efficiently?"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/441/can-a-trie-be-implemented-efficiently)

Included are timing studies suggesting empirical n*Log[n] complexity over 6 orders of magnitude.

**Generic Helper Functions**

```
jointKeyValueApply[f_][k_->v_]:=k->f[k,v]

associationKeyValueMap[f_]:=AssociationMap[jointKeyValueApply[f]]
```

This is a variation on KeyValueMap that preserves Association structure, eg:

```
<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|> // associationKeyValueMap[f]
```

> <|"a" -> f["a", 1], "b" -> f["b", 2]|>

**Quad-Index Specific Helper Functions**

```
boxMean[Rectangle[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}]] := {x0 + x1, y0 + y1}/2;

boxSplit[Rectangle[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}]] := {{x0, (x0 + x1)/2, 
    x1}, {y0, (y0 + y1)/2, y1}};
```

• boxClassify takes the truth-values output by GroupBy eg {True,False}, and maps them to coordinates.

```
boxClassify[r_Rectangle][{x_, 
    y_}] := {boxSplit[
        r], {x, y} /. {False -> {1, 2}, True -> {2, 3}}} // 
      Transpose // Map[Apply@Part] // Transpose // Apply[Rectangle];
```

• boundingBoxAssociation takes a key, eg "pos" here, and computes a bounding box and associates it as root key with the data as values.

```
 boundingBoxAssociation[pointKey_][data_List] :=  
  Query[{Query[All, pointKey] /* transposeCommute[Map[MinMax]] /* 
       Apply[Rectangle], Identity} /* Apply[Rule] /* Association][
   data];
```

**Recursive Query**

```
groupByQuad[bucketSize_][box_Rectangle, data_List] := 
  If[Length[data] > bucketSize, 
   data // GroupBy[
      Thread[#pos > boxMean[box] ] & /* boxClassify[box]] // 
    associationKeyValueMap[groupByQuad[bucketSize]], data];
```

**Indexer Function**

```
quadIndex[pointKey_, bucketSize_][data_List] := 
  boundingBoxAssociation[pointKey][data] // 
   associationKeyValueMap[groupByQuad[bucketSize]];
```

**USAGE**

**Point Cloud Association**

• Foo is a generic to illustrate that payload can be associated with each point stored in "pos" key:

```
gaussianPointData[n_] :=  
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 2}] //  
   Map[<|"pos" -> #, "foo" -> 0|> &] ;
```

**Dataset indexed to 6 orders of magnitude**

```
pointDS = <|
    Table[ToString[exp] -> gaussianPointData[10^exp], {exp, 1, 6}]|> // 
   Dataset;
```

That is:

```
pointDS[All, Length]
```

[image]

**Timing Studies**

• 2013 iMac w/ 32GB

```
timingStudy["bucket size 1"] = 
   pointDS[All, quadIndex["pos", 1] /* Timing]; // Timing
```

> {379.58, Null}

```
timingStudy["bucket size 5"] = 
   pointDS[All, quadIndex["pos", 5] /* Timing]; // Timing
```

> {285.578, Null}

• Timing by input size:

{timingStudy["bucket size 1"] [All, First], 
 timingStudy["bucket size 5"] [All, First]}

[image]

• Plot

```
ListPlot[{Normal@timingStudy["bucket size 1"] [Values, First], 
  Normal@timingStudy["bucket size 5"] [Values, 
    First], (#*Log[4, #]/30000. &)  /@ Table[10^exp, {exp, 1, 6}] }, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Figures**

• Bucket size 1, 100pts

```
timingStudy["bucket size 1"][2, 
    Last /* associationKeyFlatten][{Keys /* Flatten, 
    Query[Values, Apply[Point], "pos"]}] // 
  Normal // (Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], #}, 
    PlotRange -> 3 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True] &)
```

[image]

• bucket size 1, 1k points:

```
timingStudy["bucket size 1"][3, 
    Last /* associationKeyFlatten][{Keys /* Flatten, 
    Query[Values, Apply[Point], "pos"]}] // 
  Normal // (Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], #}, 
    PlotRange -> 3.5 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True] &)
```

[image]

• bucket size 5, 1k points:

```
timingStudy["bucket size 10"][3, 
    Last /* associationKeyFlatten][{Keys /* Flatten, 
    Query[Values, Map[Point], "pos"]}] // 
  Normal // (Graphics[{FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thin, Blue}], #}, 
    PlotRange -> 4 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Frame -> True] &)
```

[image]

**Output Description**

• Showing nested Association (trie) structure

```
timingStudy["bucket size 1"][1, Last] // Normal
```

> <|Rectangle[{-1.44554,-1.22553},{1.85318,0.992471}]-><|Rectangle[{0.203821,-0.116532},{1.85318,0.992471}]-><|Rectangle[{0.203821,0.43797},{1.0285,0.992471}]->{<|pos->{0.315051,0.992471},foo->0|>},Rectangle[{0.203821,-0.116532},{1.0285,0.43797}]->{<|pos->{0.496316,-0.0548369},foo->0|>}|>,Rectangle[{-1.44554,-0.116532},{0.203821,0.992471}]-><|Rectangle[{-0.62086,-0.116532},{0.203821,0.43797}]-><|Rectangle[{-0.20852,-0.116532},{0.203821,0.160719}]->{<|pos->{0.0416775,0.0817036},foo->0|>},Rectangle[{-0.62086,-0.116532},{-0.20852,0.160719}]->{<|pos->{-0.559806,-0.106714},foo->0|>}|>,Rectangle[{-1.44554,-0.116532},{-0.62086,0.43797}]->{<|pos->{-1.44554,-0.112904},foo->0|>}|>,Rectangle[{-1.44554,-1.22553},{0.203821,-0.116532}]-><|Rectangle[{-1.44554,-1.22553},{-0.62086,-0.671033}]-><|Rectangle[{-1.0332,-1.22553},{-0.62086,-0.948284}]-><|Rectangle[{-0.82703,-1.22553},{-0.62086,-1.08691}]-><|Rectangle[{-0.723945,-1.22553},{-0.62086,-1.15622}]->{<|pos->{-0.646667,-1.22553},foo->0|>},Rectangle[{-0.723945,-1.15622},{-0.62086,-1.08691}]->{<|pos->{-0.654308,-1.09372},foo->0|>}|>|>|>,Rectangle[{-0.62086,-1.22553},{0.203821,-0.671033}]->{<|pos->{-0.431171,-1.08481},foo->0|>},Rectangle[{-1.44554,-0.671033},{-0.62086,-0.116532}]->{<|pos->{-1.24569,-0.514815},foo->0|>}|>,Rectangle[{0.203821,-1.22553},{1.85318,-0.116532}]->{<|pos->{1.85318,-1.01392},foo->0|>}|>|>

• This is not a classical quad-tree in that GroupBy only generates keys depending on the values. For example, if a quadrant is empty, only 3 sub-notes will be generated.

• Additional services associated with such indexes such as lookup, insert, delete, are not addressed here.

Comment: Fyi > additional description and comments are availble here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1017101?p_p_auth=s6SInfY0