# Simplifying a reverse Fold for a Query

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, functional-style, query

Is there a simpler way to parametrize this tail-recursive expression to be applied as a `Query` (for processing a nested `Association`)? The pattern is shown by example with first 3 levels:

> ```
> g[f[1]]  (* level 1 *)
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2]]]  (* l2 *)
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3]]]]  (* l3 *)
> ```

The following application of `Fold` works but seems roundabout, yet couldn't find anything simpler including `ComposeList` (the generic-sounding name is for convenience, not meangingful)

```
reverseFoldCompose[f_, g_, n_] :=  
  Fold[RightComposition /* Reverse /* g, {Identity} ~ Join~ 
    Reverse@Table[f[i], {i, n}]];
```

Then:

```
Table[reverseFoldCompose[f, g, i] , {i, 4}] // Column
```

> ```
> g[f[1]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]]]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]/*g[f[4]]]]]
> ```

**EDIT:**

Is there a single approach that can handle the above and this variation with leading `f`?

```
f[1];   (* l1 *)
f[1] /* g[f[2]];  (* l2 *) 
f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3]]];  (* l3 *)
```

Hacking the function above as follows is not satisfactory as it doesn't handle level 2 and requires precomposing with `f[1]` - yuck.

```
reverseFoldCompose2[f_, g_, {m_, n_}] := 
  Fold[RightComposition /* Reverse /* g, {Identity}~Join~
    Reverse@Table[f[i], {i, m, n}]];
```

Then:

```
Table[f[1] /* reverseFoldCompose2[f, g, {2, i}], {i, 3, 5}] // Column
```

> ```
> f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]]]
> f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]/*g[f[4]]]]
> f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]/*g[f[4]/*g[f[5]]]]]
> ```

Of the approaches so far, I think Martin's is the cleanest, and this leading-f form *almost* works but for the `g[Identity]` which here is dismissed with a `Replace`:

```
Fold[f[#2] /* g[#1] &, Identity, Range[3, 1, -1]] /. g[Identity] -> Identity
```

> `f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]/*g[f[4]]]]`

Ps, I intend to use this pattern to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136641/how-to-use-classical-data-structure-in-mathematica), specifically quad-tree indexing using nested Associations.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your first example which one of the answers is based on. In the first example you have `g[f[1] /* g[f[2]] /* g[f[3]]]`, but at the end it's `g[f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]]]]` (notice the number of `]` after `2`). The latter seems more consistent.

Comment: @Martin Darn, I missed that.  Well in case someone wants the other form... :^)

Comment: @MartinEnder, good eye, I caught that last night but was too tired to edit. Also want to add a variation with a leading 'f', if that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn[f_, g_, i_] :=
  g[ f[1] /* ## & @@ Array[g@*f, i - 1, 2] ]

Array[fn[f, g, #] &, 4] // Column
```

> ```
> g[f[1]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2]]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2]] /* g[f[3]]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2]] /* g[f[3]] /* g[f[4]]]
> ```

*Oops, it seems this is a solution to a typo rather than what you actually need.*

---

Responding to your comment for a solution to your variation:

```
fn[n_] := Fold[f[#2] /* g[#] &, f[n], Range[n - 1, 1, -1]]

Array[fn, 5] // Column
```

> ```
> f[1]
> f[1] /* g[f[2]]
> f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3]]]
> f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3] /* g[f[4]]]]
> f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3] /* g[f[4] /* g[f[5]]]]]
> ```

```
Array[g@*fn, 5] // Column
```

> ```
> g[f[1]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2]]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3]]]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3] /* g[f[4]]]]]
> g[f[1] /* g[f[2] /* g[f[3] /* g[f[4] /* g[f[5]]]]]]
> ```

Comment: It seems like you've based this on the pattern in the first example, which I think has a typo. Compare the `N = 3` case of the first and last listing in the question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, sorry for the typo, I'd hand-typed it. Perhaps you can redeem by handling the variation with leading `f`? Please see my edit.

Comment: @alancalvitti I hope I got it right this time...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, these work fine. In the end however, I realized pre-packaging queries limits their use to fixed-depth processing as no state information is used. Instead I used a recursive query in the quad-tree implementation, here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137422/801

Comment: @alancalvitti That makes sense, and I look forward to studying your quadtree implementation.

Answer (score 10):

A more direct solution with `Fold` using `Range` to reverse.

With

```
rfc[f_, g_, i_Integer?Positive] :=
 Fold[g[f[#2] /* #1] &, g[f[i]], Range[i - 1, 1, -1]]
```

Then

```
rfc[f, g, #] & /@ Range[4] // Column
```

> ```
> g[f[1]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]]]]
> g[f[1]/*g[f[2]/*g[f[3]/*g[f[4]]]]]
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alternatively, `Fold[g[f[#2] /* #1] &, Identity, Range[i, 1, -1]]`.

Comment: @Edmund, can you please check my edit to see if you can handle the variation with leading `f`?

Comment: @MartinEnder, I fixed typo and added the variation. Can you please  see if your approach can easily handle both cases, and if so post a proper answer?

Comment: @MartinEnder, this *almost* works: `Fold[f[#2] /* g[#1] &, Identity, Range[i, 1, -1]]`

Comment: @alancalvitti The best I can think of is `Fold[#2 /* g[#1] &, f /@ Range[#, 1, -1]] &` but it's not really a generalisation of my other suggestion, but yet another approach.