# How to use the new DataStructure in V 12.1 as is done in classical struct?

Tags: data-structures

There is new [DataStructure](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataStructure.html) in V 12.1. I thought at first it is similar to classical struct or record found in other languages and discussed in

[Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica)

[How to use classical data structure in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136641/how-to-use-classical-data-structure-in-mathematica)

Wikipedia entry for struct is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)

To make this question concrete, suppose one wants to make this struct, which in C is

```
struct personal_info 
{ 
   char name[50]; 
   int  age; 
   char address[50]; 
};
```

Then make a variable of the above type and access the struct fields using the dot notation in C. This is similar to `record` in Pascal and Ada also.

How to use the new `DataStructure` to do this? In C one will do something like the following

```
struct personal_info my_info;   
my_info.age = 90;
fprintf("my age is %d",my_info.age);
```

I could not find one basic example in the help pages on how to actually use this new  `DataStructure`. I also looked at Wolfram blog on this, where he says

https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2020/03/in-less-than-a-year-so-much-new-launching-version-12-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/

> Think about all those data structures that get mentioned in textbooks,
>   papers, libraries, etc. Our goal is to have all of them seamlessly
>   usable directly in the Wolfram Language, and accessible in compiled
>   code, etc. Of course it’s huge that we already have a universal “data
>   structure”

But following Wolfram's examples on his blog, I still do not know how to make such a simple struct using `Datastruct` (I am not looking at queues or linked list, or other advanced structs, just the basic and most common struct).

So I tried few random things (when all else fails, I switch to the trial and error method)

```
ds = CreateDataStructure["DynamicArray"]
ds["Append", {"name" -> "doe joe", "age" -> 90, 
  "Address" -> "POBox 100, main street, California"}];
```

I used `DynamicArray` above, as I did not know what else to pick for classical struct.

But I do not think this is right at all,  as I do not know now how to obtain say the `name` back.

Ofcourse one can use `Association` for this now in Mathematica, but I thought the new `DataStructure` will do this a little easier.

Question is: How to use new `DataStructure` similar to how it is used in C?

Comment: The new `DataStructure` stuff is really an algorithms-oriented development. They're intend to make your code run faster and `struct` is already fast enough using `Association` and some object-oriented programming on top of that. Unless you're working with compiled code, there's no real reason to have a `struct` that I can see (in that case it would just make it a bit easier to implement things, I figure).

Comment: @b3m2a1 You can't compile functions with `Association` type though (as far as I know). I think the point of having `struct` data structure is to have a compilable `Typed` `Function` that can refer to its argument fields by name, and that also has exactly specified memory size inferred from its field types.

Comment: @swish Yeah that's a use case I can definitely foresee being important (if not necessary). I'm merely pointing out that if you're not working with `FunctionCompile` and friends there's gonna be no benefit to having it be a bespoke `DataStructure`

Comment: @b3m2a1 One can argue that having typed version of `Association` at hand is a huge benefit already. And consequently typed `Dataset` may bring great performance boost to the ecosystem.

Comment: @swish the issue is that `Typed` is just an annotation. It doesn't mean anything in top-level code. `Dataset` itself already _does_ use a typing system.

Comment: @b3m2a1 But what about `NumericArray`? It's basically going in the same direction.

Comment: @swish `NumericArray` is a mostly a transfer format at this point that has special use in compiled code and friends. `PackedArray` is more relevant for Mathematica programming.

Comment: struct guarantee that sequencial chunks of memory is used for storage in your RAM for components and thus data sizes need to be known beforehand. Does `Association` keep the data in sequencial chunks of memory at the time of initialization at the very least? Also the moment you try to replace an in-between item with larger size `Association` doesn't complain. Probably it stores it somewhere else and keeps track of pointers like a linked list. So `Association` might not really be a true struct down at memory level.

Comment: @user13892 No I can promise you `Association` is _not_ implemented as a `struct`. It's not memory optimizing because that's not what top-level code does... That's why we have `FunctionCompile`. Low-level features should enter where low-level features are relevant. The only place where we have an awkward intermediate is `PackedArray`.

Comment: structs are blazing fast (no doubt since their data is sitting next to each other in memory and just a single pointer at the head is enough to retrieve all it's information) while `Association` is slow as hell even for a high level language (probably is a bloated pointer spaghetti down there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best match to what you are discussing is an association, e.g.

```
personalinfo = Association["name" -> "Fred", "age" -> 90]
(* <|"name" -> "Fred", "age" -> 90|> *)

personalinfo["name"]
(* "Fred" *)
```