# Most common prefixes in an English corpus (Hamlet)

Tags: string-manipulation, data, counting

There are many resources online showing how to get the most frequent letters in the english language. What I'm trying to do is get the most common word prefixes in the english language - i.e, take a lot of text, and find the most common strings that *begin* words of length 2 or more in that text.

For the purposes of this question, I have been using the text of Hamlet. I've tried many things but I'm not sure how to approach this algorithmically, let alone implementing it.

How can I find the most common prefixes in the english language based on some text?

Comment: You can use "prefix trees with frequencies": [WordPress blog post](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2017/01/31/tries-with-frequencies-in-java/), [GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MarkdownDocuments/Tries-with-frequencies-in-Java.md) . Or see this [MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136694/34008).

Answer (score 1):

```
mytext = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their party";

Flatten[
        Table[{i <> j, 
             Length[StringCases[mytext, 
             Shortest[WordBoundary ~~ i <> j ~~ __ ~~ WordBoundary]]]}, 
        {i, CharacterRange["a", "z"]}, 
        {j, CharacterRange["a", "z"]}], 
  1] // TableForm
```

Just replace mytext with your Hamlet text.

Here are the results for the First Act, up to Horatio's speech starting "That can I..."

```
  {{"th", 65}, {"to", 23}, {"of", 22}, {"an", 21}, {"no", 14}, {"st", 
  12}, {"ha", 12}, {"yo", 11}, {"ni", 10}, {"it", 10}, {"he", 
  10}, {"so", 9}, {"ma", 9}, {"be", 9}, {"sp", 8}, {"wa", 7}, {"ki", 
  7}, {"co", 7}, {"wh", 6}, {"on", 6}, {"li", 6}, {"hi", 6}, {"go", 
  6}, {"wi", 5}, {"we", 5}, {"us", 5}, {"tw", 5}, {"se", 5}, {"ou", 
  5}, {"my", 5}, {"mo", 5}, {"ho", 5}, {"ca", 5}, {"ar", 5}, {"ag", 
  5}, {"si", 4}, {"sa", 4}, {"pa", 4}, {"mi", 4}, {"me", 4}, {"fr", 
  4}, {"fo", 4}, {"fa", 4}, {"do", 4}, {"ap", 4}, {"wo", 3}, {"ti", 
  3}, {"su", 3}, {"lo", 3}, {"le", 3}, {"la", 3}, {"is", 3}, {"in", 
  3}, {"gr", 3}, {"da", 3}, {"ch", 3}, {"bu", 3}, {"at", 3}, {"tr", 
  2}, {"ta", 2}, {"sc", 2}, {"re", 2}, {"qu", 2}, {"pr", 2}, {"po", 
  2}, {"pl", 2}, {"ne", 2}, {"kn", 2}, {"im", 2}, {"ey", 2}, {"di", 
  2}, {"de", 2}, {"by", 2}, {"br", 2}, {"bi", 2}, {"aw", 2}, {"am", 
  2}, {"al", 2}, {"ve", 1}, {"up", 1}, {"un", 1}, {"tu", 1}, {"te", 
  1}, {"sw", 1}, {"sm", 1}, {"sl", 1}, {"sh", 1}, {"ri", 1}, {"pi", 
  1}, {"ow", 1}, {"ot", 1}, {"op", 1}, {"ob", 1}, {"mu", 1}, {"ju", 
  1}, {"jo", 1}, {"il", 1}, {"if", 1}, {"ic", 1}, {"gu", 1}, {"ge", 
  1}, {"fi", 1}, {"fe", 1}, {"er", 1}, {"en", 1}, {"ea", 1}, {"dr", 
  1}, {"bo", 1}, {"av", 1}, {"as", 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already had something similar to this, but I should clarify - I'm trying to find the most common prefixes in a certain text, i.e in actual use in the english language, not just from a dictionary.

Comment: Why not identify the common prefixes using David's method (maybe extend to 3 letters as well) and then, once you have the list, search your text for them

Comment: @bill S That's a great idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the package [TriesWithFrequencies.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/TriesWithFrequencies.m) described in the blog post ["Tries with frequencies for data mining"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/06/tries-with-frequencies-for-data-mining/).

This loads the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/TriesWithFrequencies.m"]
```

This gets the words from "Hamlet" and converts to lower case:

```
tWords = TextWords[ExampleData[{"Text", "Hamlet"}]];
tWords = ToLowerCase[tWords];
Length[tWords]

(* 31874 *)
```

This creates the trie and converts the frequencies to probabilities:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 pTr = TrieNodeProbabilities[TrieCreate[tWords]];
]

(* {6.01861, Null} *)
```

Trie nodes counts:

```
TrieNodeCounts[pTr]

(* <|"total" -> 14276, "internal" -> 10502, "leaves" -> 3774|> *)
```

The following code prunes the trie in correspondence to a given prefix length and then finds the corresponding probabilities for each prefix. The result is given as an Association.

```
maxPrefixLength = 3;
paths = Rest /@ TrieRootToLeafPaths[TriePrune[pTr, maxPrefixLength]];
aPaths = Map[<|"path" -> Apply[StringJoin, #[[All, 1]]], 
     "probability" -> Apply[Times, #[[All, 2]]]|> &, paths];
```

From this Pareto principle adherence plot we can see that 20% of the 3-letter prefixes are correspond to 80% of the words in "Hamlet":

```
ParetoLawPlot[Through[aPaths["probability"]]]
```

[image]

This finds quantile values within the 10% of the most popular prefixes:

```
Quantile[Through[aPaths["probability"]], Range[0.9, 1, 0.025]]

(* {0.00125494, 0.00169417, 0.00257263, 0.00370208, 0.0528958} *)
```

This selects the most popular prefixes for a given probability:

```
Select[aPaths, #["probability"] >= %[[-2]] &]

(* {<|"path" -> "que", "probability" -> 0.00429817|>, <|"path" -> "kin", 
  "probability" -> 0.00715317|>, <|"path" -> "wil", 
  "probability" -> 0.00605509|>, <|"path" -> "wit", 
  "probability" -> 0.0110435|>, <|"path" -> "whe", 
  "probability" -> 0.00464328|>, <|"path" -> "wha", 
  "probability" -> 0.00696492|>, <|"path" -> "you", 
  "probability" -> 0.0267616|>, <|"path" -> "let", 
  "probability" -> 0.00370208|>, <|"path" -> "lor", 
  "probability" -> 0.00737278|>, <|"path" -> "his", 
  "probability" -> 0.00944343|>, <|"path" -> "him", 
  "probability" -> 0.00680806|>, <|"path" -> "her", 
  "probability" -> 0.00542762|>, <|"path" -> "hea", 
  "probability" -> 0.00624333|>, <|"path" -> "hor", 
  "probability" -> 0.00545899|>, <|"path" -> "hav", 
  "probability" -> 0.00586685|>, <|"path" -> "ham", 
  "probability" -> 0.0148397|>, <|"path" -> "but", 
  "probability" -> 0.00843948|>, <|"path" -> "our", 
  "probability" -> 0.00429817|>, <|"path" -> "all", 
  "probability" -> 0.00401581|>, <|"path" -> "are", 
  "probability" -> 0.00407856|>, <|"path" -> "and", 
  "probability" -> 0.0307147|>, <|"path" -> "not", 
  "probability" -> 0.0110749|>, <|"path" -> "pol", 
  "probability" -> 0.00432955|>, <|"path" -> "com", 
  "probability" -> 0.00655707|>, <|"path" -> "sho", 
  "probability" -> 0.00389032|>, <|"path" -> "sha", 
  "probability" -> 0.00467466|>, <|"path" -> "for", 
  "probability" -> 0.0115141|>, <|"path" -> "tho", 
  "probability" -> 0.00611784|>, <|"path" -> "tha", 
  "probability" -> 0.0149024|>, <|"path" -> "thi", 
  "probability" -> 0.0129573|>, <|"path" -> "the", 
  "probability" -> 0.0528958|>} *)
```