# How to make an Association of Assocations

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset, associations

As a learning exercise I’m trying to convert some data we have from spreadsheets into an association of associations. However, I’ve only managed to format two different associations, a key of the element’s area and a list of elements in each group (1-49). I’ve tried things like `ReplaceMap`, `KeyMap`, and `AssociationMap` but I’m missing some logic for all these approaches to work. An association of associations seems like an excellent & natural way to structure this data but I can’t figure out how to do it. I’m trying to associate each element’s area to the matching element in the group so that further computation and manipulation can been done. I’d eventually like the ability to add other characteristics to each element type beyond just its area.

**Element Key**  `unitkey`

```
<| S1-01->569, S1-02->518, S1-03->461.5, S1-04->570.6, S1-05->617.3, S1-06->631.4
, S1D-01->571.7, S1D-02->647.4,S1D-03->762.2,S1D-04->687.3,S1D-05->691.5,S1D-06->756.4,S1D-07->653.5,S1D-08->783.2,S1D-09->639.3
, S2-01->867.1,S2-02->809.3,S2-03->974.1,S2-04->826.4,S2-05->852,S2-06->852.5,S2-07->865.4,S2-08->865.2,S2-09->1023.4
,S2D-01->890, S2D-03->965.2,S2D-04->861.8,S2D-05->1028.9,S2D-06->986.1,S2D-08->1074.4,S2D-09->1062.6,S2D-10->1007.5
, TH-04->1488,TH-03->1424,TH-02->1352,TH-01->1312
|>
```

**Elements by Group** `unitsbylevel`

```
<|1 -> {"TH-01", "TH-02", "TH-03", "TH-04"}, 
 2 -> {"S2D-09", "S1D-09", "S1-05", "S1-06"}, 
 3 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03","S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 4 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 5 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 6 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 7 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 8 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 9 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",        "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 10 -> {"S2-04", "S2D-09", "S1D-01", "S1-01", "S1-01", "S1D-03",      "S2D-05", "S2-03", "S2-06", "S2-07", "S2D-04"}, 
 11 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-08", "S2D-05",      "S2D-06", "S2-05", "S2D-01", "S2-08"}, 
 12 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-08", "S2D-05",      "S2D-06", "S2-05", "S2D-01", "S2-08"}, 
 13 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-08", "S2D-05",      "S2D-06", "S2-05", "S2D-01", "S2-08"}, 
 14 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-08", "S2D-05",      "S2D-06", "S2-05", "S2-08"}, 
 15 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 16 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 17 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
18 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 19 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 20 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 21 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 22 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 23 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 24 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 25 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 26 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 27 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 28 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 29 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 30 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 31 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 32 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
33 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 34 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 35 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 36 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 37 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 38 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 39 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 40 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 41 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 42 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 43 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 44 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 45 -> {"S1D-07", "S2-01", "S1-03", "S1-03", "S1D-06", "S1-04",       "S1D-04", "S1-02", "S1-02", "S2-02"}, 
 46 -> {"S2D-08", "S1D-02", "S2D-10", "S2-09", "S1D-05", "S2D-03"}, 
47 -> {"S2D-08", "S1D-02", "S2D-10", "S2-09", "S1D-05", "S2D-03"}, 
 48 -> {"S2D-08", "S1D-02", "S2D-10", "S2-09", "S1D-05", "S2D-03"}, 
 49 -> {"S2D-08", "S1D-02", "S2D-10", "S2-09", "S1D-05", "S2D-03"}
|>
```

**Update 2018-08-23**

Added an example of what group 2 would theoretically look like.

```
<|2 -> <| S2D-09 ->  1062.6 , S1D-09 -> 639.3, S1-05->617.3, S1-06->631.4 |> |>
```

Comment: This might be semi-related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171104/how-can-i-create-an-association-from-a-multidimensional-list-of-values-and-a-lis.

Comment: I am not sure what is the expected result. Can you show a minimal example of input that comes from `Import[file.xlsx]` to work with? Can be 5x5x5. And a corresponding result?

Comment: The two association lists above are from two different CSV files generated from Excel. I'm trying to merge them into a hierarchy. Groups > type and number of elements in each group > each specific element's area from the key.

Comment: Lack of attention probably comes from the fact that `<| S2D-09 ->  1062.6...` is an invalid mma syntax, you are missing quotes around `S2D-09`: `"S2D-09"`, so if you want anyone to play with your data you should provide a valid one.

Comment: Agree w Kuba that you're shooting yourself in the foot by not wrapping the keys in your first association in quotes. Once that's done, it's a simple: map `AssociationMap[elementKeyAssociation]` on each of the lists of keys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get the exact structure I needed with the below quoted code. Not sure how best yet to visualize it or manipulate it but thats the fun part.

```
find[x_String]:=unitkey[[x]]
data = AssociationMap[Association[#->find[#] &/@ unitsbylevel[[#]]]&, Range[Length@unitsbylevel]];
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: `unitsbylevel` is not defined and it is not clear how 'elements by key' and 'elements by group' are used here making this answer useless for anyone but you. :-/